# What does the question mark character ('?') mean in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, conditional-operator

```
int qempty()
{
    return (f == r ? 1 : 0);
}
```

In the above snippet, what does "?" mean?  What can we replace it with?

Comment: In this particular case of course, you can just replace it with return f==r;

Comment: @Eclipse: I wouldn't rely on an implicit conversion bool->int if I can avoid it.

Comment: @DanielDaranas why not? (This is kind of a beginner question- an explanation of your comments for beginners would be very helpful and appreciated.)

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann The behaviour of the implicit conversion in this case is well defined, so using it is perfectly correct; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5369783/96780) for a reference to the standard. Personally, I avoid using implicit type conversions because I think the code is more readable and maintainable and less error prone without them. I wrote in more detail about it in this [blog post](http://thedeepbluecpp.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/rule-2-make-all-type-conversions.html).

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as the [**conditional operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), and when used like this:

```
condition ? result_if_true : result_if_false
```

... if the `condition` evaluates to `true`, the expression evaluates to `result_if_true`, otherwise it evaluates to `result_if_false`.

It is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), and in this case, it can be replaced with

```
int qempty()
{ 
  if(f == r)
  {
      return 1;
  } 
  else 
  {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Some people refer to `?:` it as "**the ternary operator**", because it is the only ternary operator (i.e. operator that takes three arguments) in the language they are using.

Comment: In regular code, it's syntactic sugar, but it does enable you to do conditional initialization in the initialization list of the constructot.

Comment: Foo(Bar* y) pMember (y == NULL ? NULL : y->pMember) -- Here, we initialize pMember to y's pMember, or NULL if it's not there.  Can't put if-else in a constructor initialization, so ternary operator makes it possible.

Comment: @JohnMcG: Well, in C++11 you could consider `a? b : c` syntactic sugar for `[&]() -> Type { if (a) return b; else return c; }()`.

Comment: Probably, but the question, answer, and comment were written in 2009.

Answer (score 17):

This is a ternary operator, it's basically an inline if statement

```
x ? y : z
```

works like

```
if(x) y else z
```

except, instead of statements you have expressions; so you can use it in the middle of a more complex statement.

It's useful for writing succinct code, but can be overused to create hard to maintain code.

Comment: worthwhile to know that there is a sequence point at the '?'. That means the following is valid: ++x ? x : y;

Comment: @Daniel, that's what I meant by having expressions rather than statements.  I probably wasn't explicit enough about the difference,  so thanks for adding some clarification.

Answer (score 13):

Just a note, if you ever see this:

```
a = x ? : y;
```

It's a GNU extension to the standard (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

It is the same as

```
a = x ? x : y;
```

Comment: in CLang (at least the most recent versions) this extension is also available. It's available even with C++11 flag turned off in a qmake project.

So an expression like int `x = 1+1 ? : 0 `; correctly returns  `2 `, in my compiler and this didn't complain anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can just rewrite it as:

```
int qempty(){ return(f==r);}
```

Which does the same thing as said in the other answers.

Comment: this would perform implicit conversion from boolean to int

Answer (score 5):

It is called the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

You can replace it with:

```
int qempty(){ 
    if (f == r) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the conditional operator.

a ? b : c

It's a shortcut for IF/THEN/ELSE.

means: if a is true, return b, else return c.  In this case, if f==r, return 1, else return 0.

Answer (score 2):

The question mark is the conditional operator. The code means that if f==r then 1 is returned, otherwise, return 0. The code could be rewritten as

```
int qempty()
{
  if(f==r)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

which is probably not the cleanest way to do it, but hopefully helps your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

It read as:

```
If f == r then return 1 else return 0
```