# Help me understand this code

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
```

Can someone help me understand the above code? I'm fairly new to php :) What up with `?` and `:`?

I would appreciate it!

Comment: This is a duplicate, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/php-operator.

Comment: it's a duplicate of many questions on here, docs are here: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php

Answer (score 7):

This is a ternary operator. This basically says

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else
{
   $id = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary).

What is says that is if `$_GET['id']` is set, `$id` is `intval($_GET['id'])`, otherwise, `$id` is 0.

Comment: It’s *a* ternary operator, not “the”.

Comment: As Jon Skeet says: 'It's not **the** ternary operator, but **a** ternary operator.'

Comment: @Gumbo - stole the words out of my mouth!

Comment: I think that should make it all bette.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` and `:` are parts of an inline `if`.

Basically, if `isset($_GET['id'])` is true, `intval($_GET['id'])` is used. Otherwise, `$id` gets 0.

Comment: `if` is a statement but `?:` is an operator. That’s a difference!

Answer (score 1):

x ? y : z = if x is true then y else z

Answer (score 1):

That’s the [*conditional operator*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) :

> The expression *`(expr1)`* `?` *`(expr2)`* `:` *`(expr3)`* evaluates to *`expr2`* if *`expr1`* evaluates to *TRUE*, and *`expr3`* if *`expr1`* evaluates to *FALSE*.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly this:

```
$id = 0;
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is short notation for an `if`.  The notation is taken from C.

It could be re-written:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) ) {
     $id = intval($_GET['id']);
} else {
     $id = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called a ternary

it populates $id with intval($_GET['id']) if isset($_GET['id']) returns true else it will populate it with 0

Answer (score 0):

see:
http://www.lizjamieson.co.uk/2007/08/20/short-if-statement-in-php/
and
http://php.net/operators.comparison

Answer (score 0):

If $_GET['id'] exists it sets $id = $_GET['id'], if not it sets $id = 0, it uses ternary. https://www.php.net/ternary

Answer (score 0):

This is just shorthand for an if statement ([ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)) and is the same as:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else
{
    $id = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a ternary operator. Basically, it has a

```
if (condition) {

} else {

}
```

in one line.

The code says

If the GET var id has been set, then set the $id var to equal the integer of the GET's variable.

For arguments sake too, casting with `(int)` has been proven to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

That statement essentially means this:

```
$id = 0;

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else
{
    $id = 0;
}
```

The `?:` operator means "if condition then result else other_result," all in one line.  You're basically setting the value of the $id variable based on a `boolean` (`true/false`) condition.  If the condition is true, the first result is used to set the value of the `$id` variable.  Otherwise, it uses the second value.