# Explain this PHP shorthand

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

I feed like a goof but I don't entirely understand what's happening in this code:

```
$var .= ($one || $two) ? function_one( $one, $another) : function_two( $two, $another);
```

Does that say if $one or $two then $var is equal to fuction_one(), else function_two()? What's the purpose of using this syntax -- speed?

Comment: Good ol' ternary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: This is closed, but regarding what it's used for - speed and cleaner code as this example shows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator#Usage

Comment: Thanks everyone for the overwhelming response!

Comment: For what it's worth, it's hard to figure out if your question is a duplicate if your question is "what is this?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If either `$one` is true, or `$two` is true, then the result of calling `function_one` is appended to `$var`. Otherwise, the result of calling `function_two` is appended to `$var`.

It's basically shorthand for:

```
if ($one || $two) {
  $var .= function_one( $one, $another);
} else {
  $var .= function_two( $two, $another);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$var` would append to itself the value from the return of `function_one()` if `$one` or `$two` evaluates to true, and would append the result of `function_two()` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`function_one()` and `function_two()` both return a value.

You are concatenating `$var` to the return value of one of these function based on an if statement that evaluates `$one` or `$two`,  If `$one` or `$tow` are assigned or return true the returned from `function_one()` is concatenated otherwise the value returned from `function_tow()` is.

Answer (score 1):

$var .= ($one || $two) ? function_one( $one, $another) : function_two( $two, $another);

append $var with output of function_one() or function_two()

if $one is true then execute function_one() else execute function_two()