# What does this PHP (function/construct?) do, and where can I find more documentation on it?

Tags: php

Simple question. Here is this code.

```
    $r = rand(0,1);
    $c = ($r==0)? rand(65,90) : rand(97,122);
    $inputpass .= chr($c);
```

I understand what it does in the **end** result, but I'd like a better explanation on how it works, so I can use it myself. Sorry if this is a bad question.

If you're unsure of what I'm asking about, its the (function?) used here:

`$c = ($r==0)? rand(65,90) : rand(97,122);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: +1 for being willing to ask the question to figure out what's going on instead of using it blindly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called a ternary operator. It's effectively the equivalent of

```
if ($r == 0) {
    $c = rand(65, 90);
} else {
    $c = rand(97, 122);
}
```

But it's obviously a bit more compact. Check out the [docs](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for more info.

Comment: And of course this means it can't have any `else if` statements?

Comment: @Rob Well, you could nest ternaries if you like to get the same effect, but it gets messy: `$c = $r == 0 ? rand(65, 90) : ($r == 1 ? something : rand(97, 122));`. If you want else ifs, I'd always go for an explicit if statement.

Comment: Seems crazy. Thanks for the help, Chris

Answer (score 1):

That simply means:

```
if($r==0){
  $c = rand(65,90);
else{
  $c = rand(97,122);
}
```

If the statement is true the first operation after that `?` is executed, else the operation after `:` is executed.

Its called a [ternary operator](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/11/11/php-ternary-operator/).

Answer (score 0):

Its the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
<?php
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

?>
```

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.
>   Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the ternary operator.  It's similar to an if/else construct, but the difference is that an expression using the ternary operator yields a value.

That is, you can't set a variable to the result of an if/else construct:

```
// this doesn't work:
$c = if ($r == 0) {
         rand(65, 90);
     } else {
         rand(97, 122);
     }
```

You can read more about it here: http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary

The ternary operator is frequently misused.  There's little benefit to using it in the example you showed.  Some programmers love to use compact [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) even when it's not needed.  Or even when it's more clear to write out the full if/else construct.

The ternary operator can also obscure test coverage if you use a tool that measures lines of code covered by tests.