# PHP Programming Syntax Question 'x ? x : x;'

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

I've been programming PHP for years, but have never understood what this syntax does or means.  I'm hoping you guys can explain it to me, it's about time I knew the answer:

```
list($name, $operator) = (strpos($key, '__')) ? explode('__', $key) : array($key, null);
```

Specifically, I'm curious about the SOMETHING ? SOMETHING : SOMETHING;

Comment: It's a conditional operator : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shorthand for `if() { } else {}`.

```
if($i == 0) {
  echo 'hello';
} else {
  echo 'byebye';
}
```

is the same as:

```
echo $i == 0 ? 'hello' : 'byebye';
```

Answer (score 0):

The first statement after '?' is executed if the first expression before '?' is true, if not the last is executed. It also **evaluates** to the value of the executed expression.

Answer (score 0):

Its conditional operator just like if in simple words if in one line

`(condition) ? statement1 : statement2`

If condition is `true` then execute **statement1** else **statement2**

Answer (score 0):

this is the pure if else tertiary operation

```
if(a==b) {
    c = 3;
} else {
    c = 4;
}
```

this is same as

```
c = (a==b) ? 3:4;
```