# PHP Shorthand Explanation

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

What does this mean in longform? I haven't seen a line like this.

```
$max_o = $max_o > $o ? $max_o : $o;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as saying:

```
if($max_o <= $o) {
    $max_o = $o;
}
```

But in longhand it says

```
if($max_o > $o) {
    $max_o = $max_o;
}
else {
    $max_o = $o;
}
```

Which is rather pointless.  This is a poor usage of the ternary operator since my first simple example would do just as well.

Comment: +1 for least code, though the construct in the question does include an "else".

Comment: yep, I thought the same thing after I posted, as you can see I edited my answer

Comment: +1 For answering the question and giving an alternate solution.

Comment: Thanks! helped me out, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($max_o > $o)
{
    $max_o = $max_o;
}
else
{
    $max_o = $o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the php [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator.
It is like the following code:

```
if ($max_o > o)
  $max_o = $max_o;
else
  $max_o = $o;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is a ternary operator

it is the same as typing

```
if ($max_o > $o) {
    $max_o = $max_o;
} else {
    $max_o = $o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to write is:

```
$max_o = max($max_o, $o);
```

Apart from that, the thing's called [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and is a shortcut syntax for an `if`-statement.