# What does "isset($x) ? $y : $z" mean?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [What are the PHP operators "?" and ":" called and what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247) 
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139)

I know what `isset` means in PHP. But I have seen syntax like `isset($x) ? $y : $z`. What does it mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do) (along with several others linked from the [Stackoverflow PHP Wiki Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), also called the "conditional expression operator" (thanks Oli Charlesworth). Your code reads like:

```
if $x is set, use $y, if not use $z
```

Comment: Hah, this is the second time you've beat me to an answer by 10 seconds.

Comment: It is more accurately called the "conditional expression operator".

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, and many other languages, you can assign a value based on a condition in a 1 line statement.

```
$variable = expression ? "the expression was true" : "the expression was false".
```

This is equivalent to

```
if(expression){
    $variable="the expression is true";
}else{
    $variable="the expression is false";
}
```

You can also nest these

```
$x = (expression1) ?
     (expression2) ? "expression 1 and expression 2 are true" : "expression 1 is true but expression 2 is not" :
     (expression2) ? "expression 2 is true, but expression 1 is not" : "both expression 1 and expression 2 are false.";
```

Answer (score 2):

That statement won't do anything as written.

On the other hand something like

```
$w = isset($x) ? $y : $z;
```

is more meaningful. If $x satisfies isset(), $w is assigned $y's value. Otherwise, $w is assigned $z's value.

Answer (score 0):

It means if `$x` variable is not set , then value of `$y` is assigned to `$x` , else value of `$z` is assigned to `$x`.

Answer (score 0):

It's shorthand for a single expression if/else block.

```
$v = isset($x) ? $y : $z;

// equivalent to 
if (isset($x)) {
   $v = $y;
} else {
   $v = $z;
}
```