# PHP return syntax

Tags: php, syntax, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Can someone please tell me what this 'return' php code means / does:

```
return ($status=='SUCCESS' && $blocked=='YES') ? $reason : false;
```

I'm familiar with the regular `return $variable` type of statements in php, but I don't get what the specific brackets ( ) and ? question marks and the ": false" does.

(this is the return statement at the end of a php function)

Comment: Almost (its very similar but the link's question lacks the &&). I didn't find it when i was searching.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was interrupted. This is missing this very important question here as reference: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) - Whenever you run about some symbol you do not understand, that is a really good reference (next to the manual, it's sometimes hard to even search for these that's why that reference is worth to bookmark).

Answer (score 2):

It's a [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It's basically a shorthand notation for if/else.

In your example it would read like: If `$status` is equal to "success" and `$blocked` is equal to "Yes" return `$reason`, else, return `false`;

Comment: thanks for the perfect explanation - Exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

That's a ternary, or conditional operator, it's the same as if you had:

```
if($status=='SUCCESS' && $blocked=='YES'){
return $reason;}
else{
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the same as this:

```
if($status == 'SUCCESS' && $blocked == 'YES')
{
    return $reason;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```