# isset PHP isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : ''

Tags: php, isset

I am looking to expand on my PHP knowledge, and I came across something I am not sure what it is or how to even search for it.  I am looking at php.net isset code, and I see `isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : ''`

I understand normal isset operations, such as `if(isset($_GET['something']){ If something is exists, then it is set and we will do something }` but I don't understand the ?, repeating the get again, the : or the ''.  Can someone help break this down for me or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the PHP ? : operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It's commonly referred to as 'shorthand' or the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
$test = isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : '';
```

means

```
if(isset($_GET['something'])) {
    $test = $_GET['something'];
} else {
    $test = '';
}
```

To break it down:

```
$test = ... // assign variable
isset(...) // test
? ... // if test is true, do ... (equivalent to if)
: ... // otherwise... (equivalent to else)
```

Or...

```
// test --v
if(isset(...)) { // if test is true, do ... (equivalent to ?)
    $test = // assign variable
} else { // otherwise... (equivalent to :)
```

Comment: This isn't really plain.

Answer (score 17):

In PHP 7 you can write it even shorter:

```
$age = $_GET['age'] ?? 27;
```

This means that the `$age` variable will be set to the `age` parameter if it is provided in the URL, or it will default to 27.

See all [new features of PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

Answer (score 8):

That's called a ternary operator and it's mainly used in place of an if-else statement.

In the example you gave it can be used to retrieve a value from an array given isset returns true

```
isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : ''
```

is equivalent to

```
if (isset($_GET['something'])) {
 echo "Your error message!";
} else {
 $test = $_GET['something'];
}
```

echo $test;

Of course it's not much use unless you assign it to something, and possibly even assign a default value for a user submitted value.

```
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : 'anonymous'
```

Comment: The code blocks in the if-else conditional statement are swapped: the error should be output in case the parameter is missing.

Comment: fix code - if (!isset($_GET['something'])) - put ! befor isset

Answer (score 4):

You have encountered the [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).  It's purpose is that of a basic if-else statement.  The following pieces of code do the same thing.

Ternary:

```
$something = isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : "failed";
```

If-else:

```
if (isset($_GET['something'])) {
    $something = $_GET['something'];
} else {
    $something = "failed";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is called the ternary operator. It is shorthand for an if-else block. See here for an example http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 1):

? is called Ternary (conditional) operator : [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_conditional_operator_examples.htm)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is called a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), and you can find the [PHP implementation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  It's an `if else` statement.

```
if (isset($_GET['something']) == true) {
    thing = isset($_GET['something']);
} else {
    thing = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an empty string default then a preferred way is one of these (depending on your need):

```
$str_value = strval($_GET['something']);
$trimmed_value = trim($_GET['something']);
$int_value = intval($_GET['somenumber']);
```

If the url parameter `something` **doesn't exist in the url** then `$_GET['something']` **will return `null`**

`strval($_GET['something'])` -> `strval(null)` -> `""`

and your variable `$value` is set to an empty string.

- `trim()` might be prefered over `strval()` depending on code (e.g. a Name parameter might want to use it)
- `intval()` if only numeric values are expected and the default is zero. `intval(null)` -> `0`

Cases to consider:

`...&something=value1&key2=value2` (typical)

`...&key2=value2` (parameter missing from url $_GET will return null for it)

`...&something=+++&key2=value` (parameter is `"   "`)

**Why this is a preferred approach:**

- It fits neatly on one line and is clear what's going on.
- It's readable than `$value = isset($_GET['something']) ? $_GET['something'] : '';`
- Lower risk of copy/paste mistake or a typo: `$value=isset($_GET['something'])?$_GET['somthing']:'';`
- It's compatible with older and newer php.

---

**Update**
Strict mode may require something like this:

```
$str_value = strval(@$_GET['something']);
$trimmed_value = trim(@$_GET['something']);
$int_value = intval(@$_GET['somenumber']);
```