# PHP set value of id

Tags: php

I have some text containing variable data.

```
My age is: <span class="var" id="age">54</span> and my name is <span class="var" id="name">Matt</span>
```

If no url paramater is set then the page uses 54 which is correct, however if I set age in the url such as `?age=20` then I would like the age to be set to 20.

The text is from the database and is set to a variable called `$content`.

*Not a duplicate*. The text comes from the database and only needs to be replaced is a url param is set

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php -- it should square you away.

Comment: Can I not set the id using dom

Comment: this question may can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126420/isset-php-isset-getsomething-getsomething

Comment: Do you want to change the value in the database, or just change what is displayed on a per page view basis? If the latter, is a javascript solution acceptable (because it would be dead simple)

Comment: Yes, Steve just on the page. However, I can have a few variable fields in an article such as name age, town etc. These all need to be replaces if exist as a url param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a "condition" for the age to be displayed, therefore you will have to use PHP `if else` to check the date. Below is the code that you can use along with the explanation.

Assuming that the below is the string what you get from your db field.

```
$fetched_string = '<p> My Smith from <span class="var" id="town">Manchester, aged, <span >class="var" id="age">54</span>';
```

Now you have to extract the age, which is always in between `id="age">` and `</span>`

The best way to do this is by creating a PHP function for this.

```
function str_between($string, $searchStart, $searchEnd, $offset = 0) {
        $startPosition = strpos($string, $searchStart, $offset);
        if ($startPosition !== false) {
            $searchStartLength = strlen($searchStart);
            $endPosition = strpos($string, $searchEnd, $startPosition + 1);
            if ($endPosition !== false) {
                return substr($string, $startPosition + $searchStartLength, $endPosition - $searchStartLength);
            }
            return substr($string, $startPosition + $searchStartLength);
        }
        return $string;
    }
```

Now you simply have to pass the string values on the left (which will be the searchStart) and the right (searchEnd) of the fetched age. Below is the code to do this.

```
$fetched_age = str_between($fetched_string, 'id="age">', '</span>');
```

Based on this, I have revised the final code that you can use as is.

```
//To get the data from a URL, $_GET method is used. First you will check if the "age" has been set in the URL or not. This is done by:

function str_between($string, $searchStart, $searchEnd, $offset = 0) {
    $startPosition = strpos($string, $searchStart, $offset);

    if ($startPosition !== false) {
        $searchStartLength = strlen($searchStart);
        $endPosition = strpos($string, $searchEnd, $startPosition + 1);

        if ($endPosition !== false) {
            return substr($string, $startPosition + $searchStartLength, $endPosition - $searchStartLength);
        }

        return substr($string, $startPosition + $searchStartLength);
    }

    return $string;
}

//Fetched String for db
$fetched_string = $row['full_string'];

//This will give you the age
$fetched_age = str_between($fetched_string, 'id="age">', '</span>');

if (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    //If age is set in the URL, assign it to the PHP Variable
    $age_display = $_GET['age'];
}
else {
    //If age is not set, then assign the age fetched from the db.
    $age_display = $fetched_age;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The problem is the I have lots of different articles so nothing is hard coded. The age 54 is set in an article and stored in the database. If the age variable exists then I want to replace this on the page.

Comment: From where are you getting `?age=20`? Also identify from where are you getting age 54 as well. This will help in solving the problem.

Comment: 54 is set in an article and stored in the database. ?age=20 is a url paramater which is exists needs to replace the 54

Comment: I have edited the answer based on what you require. In case you require further assistance, please share the code that is fetching the age from your db.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, something like that however the 54 is not in a separate column, it is in a paragraph of text

Comment: Ah, OK. You mean you have to fetch is from a string? Can you share the full string (paragraph) structure/format you have stored in the db?

Comment: <p> My Smith from <span class="var" id="town">Manchester, aged, <span >class="var" id="age">54</span>   - The reason I have the span tag is I thought this may be able to help set the values in php

Comment: Are you storing this with the HTML tags in the db? If yes, it is a very bad strategy. If no, share what is fetched from the db field.

Comment: Yes because I have many articles for a news style website and I am using the tinymce text editor to create the content

Comment: Alright. Will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Check the update code. I guess this is what you are looking for. The function that I have written will not only help you in extracting the age, but you can also extract other details if required. Simply fill in the start and end string as explained.

Comment: Works, great. Thanks!

Comment: Good. If it worked, accept the answer to close this question.