# Display image if input value is number/numeric, display text if input value is not number, display nothing if input value is 0

Tags: php, input, user-input

I've been trying to customize a portion of PHP script for this.

I want it to display image if the input value is in number (1, 3, 20, 99, or etc). Else, I want it to display text if the input value is in text (lorem, randomtext, or etc). And I want it to display nothing if the value is 0.

But I keep getting it wrong. It always displays text, no matter what the input value is.

Here is the PHP code:

```
if ( $topic['topic_icon']     = $topic['icon_id']  ) {
                if (is_numeric($topic['icon_id'])) {
                "<img src='".$ibforums->vars['img_url']."/icon{$topic['icon_id']}.gif' alt='{$topic['icon_id']}' />";
                } else {
                "<span class='text-icon {$topic['icon_id']}'>{$topic['icon_id']}</span>";
                }
            } else {
             "";
             }
```

And here is a portion of the HTML where user can input the value (it's with radio button, the `<form />` tag is not included since it's a part of huge chunk of code):

```
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="15" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="{$ibforums->vars['img_url']}/icon15.gif"  align='middle' alt='' />
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="16" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="{$ibforums->vars['img_url']}/icon16.gif"  align='middle' alt='' />
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="17" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="{$ibforums->vars['img_url']}/icon17.gif"  align='middle' alt='' /><br />
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="SPRING" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='text-icon SPRING'>SPRING</span>
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="SUMMER" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='text-icon SUMMER'>SUMMER</span>
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="AUTUMN" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='text-icon AUTUMN'>AUTUMN</span>
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="WINTER" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='text-icon WINTER'>WINTER</span><br />
<input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="iconid" value="0" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;[ Use None ]
```

The column used in MySQL table (it's `icon_id`) is set as `varchar(64)`.

I apologize for the long title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know I shouldn't try to code when I'm sleepy... this is pure of my stupidity.

This is the original code:

```
$topic['topic_icon']     = $topic['icon_id']
                          ? "<img src='".$ibforums->vars['img_url']."/icon{$topic['icon_id']}.gif' alt='{$topic['icon_id']}' />&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                          : "";
```

I should've un-shortcut it first. Without the ternary operator shortcut, it should've been written as this:

```
if ( $topic['icon_id'] ) {
                $topic['topic_icon'] =  "<img src='".$ibforums->vars['img_url']."/icon{$topic['icon_id']}.gif' alt='{$topic['icon_id']}' />&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        } else {
                $topic['topic_icon'] = "";
        }
```

And then, to achieve what I need, it just needs a little additional `IF`:

```
if ( $topic['icon_id'] ) {
            if (is_numeric($topic['icon_id'])) {
                $topic['topic_icon'] =  "<img src='".$ibforums->vars['img_url']."/icon{$topic['icon_id']}.gif' alt='{$topic['icon_id']}' />&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            } else {
                $topic['topic_icon'] =  "<span class='text-icon {$topic['icon_id']}'>{$topic['icon_id']}</span>";
            }
        } else {
                $topic['topic_icon'] = "";
        }
```

Ta-da, works like a charm. Not sure though if this is the best practice (I feel it could've been done better). But it still works anyway.

Thank you for @jtheman as his answer hints me what I have done it wrong and especially thanks @JohnT ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080257 ) to make me realize where I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial IF condition contain a =, that is not a comparison operator but should be ==

```
if ( $topic['topic_icon'] == $topic['icon_id']  ) {
```

Then you seem to be missing the echo command:

```
 if (is_numeric($topic['icon_id'])) {
            echo "<img src='".$ibforums->vars['img_url']."/icon{$topic['icon_id']}.gif' alt='{$topic['icon_id']}' />";
            } else {
            echo "<span class='text-icon {$topic['icon_id']}'>{$topic['icon_id']}</span>";
            }
} else {
        echo  "";
         }
```

You does not specify how the contents of $topic array is set. Possible typo is the radio buttons name `iconid` but `$topic['icon_id']` (with _)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any difference, it still displays as text even with the `echo` command. And having `==` instead of `=` makes it shows nothing at all..

Comment: Well you can't use just = anyway. Makes the IF condition fail! What is in your $topic array then?

Comment: I'm not sure... I'm only modifying a PHP script and everything else inside the function seem to use only `=`. Here is the function: http://pastebin.com/fYk35FEJ I included the original code which I'm trying to modify there. It's working with the original (but it can only display image), while it's not working with my modification.

Comment: Your modified script is wrong. Please paste the original. Also, what are you trying to do? Why should `topic_icon` equal `icon_id`? Sounds like a stupid `if-statement` to me.

Comment: In what context is render_entry() used? Also the IF condition have been wrong also before then...

Comment: Ah, I've found the solution. It's mostly part of my stupidity. Thanks a lot for the answer, it hints me. :)