# Can AnyOne Explain this Code me Please

Tags: php

```
    $odd= true;
echo ($odd == true) ? '<tr class="odd_row">' : '<tr class="even_row">';
    $odd = !$odd;
```

Please Can Any One Explain this code?

Comment: what is confusing here?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `[a] ? [b] : [c]` is called [*ternary operator*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It is the same as this function:

```
function ternary($a, $b, $c) {
  if ($a)
    return $b;
  else
    return $c;
}
```

except that the arguments to the ternary operator are lazy evaluated (i.e. only one of `[b]` and `[c]` is actually executed).

`$odd = !$odd` toggles the value of `$odd` between `true` and `false`.

The code is probably used inside a loop that prints table rows that alternatingly have classes `odd_row`  and `even_row`, which can then be styled differently using CSS.

Comment: +1 for explaining "toggles the value of $odd between true and false"

Comment: It's not exactly the same as your function, consider `echo $a ? 1 : (print "hello");` vs `ternary($a, 1, (print "hello"));`

Comment: i know that but the main motive for asking is thiat

Answer (score 3):

This means

```
if ($odd == true){
    echo '<tr class="odd_row">';
}else{
    echo '<tr class="even_row">';
}
```

and is called [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Then by `$odd = !$odd;` the value of this variable is "flipped". I guess it's done to make the next row to be "even".

Comment: what about `$odd = !$odd;` ?

Comment: this is equivalent to :

    <?php
    if ($odd == true)
        $odd = false;
    else
        $odd = true;
</pre>

Comment: @Akam, ok, added the explanation

Comment: ya k102 it make next row even act. i didnot understand the mean of $odd = !$odd

Answer (score 0):

This is setting the `$odd` variable to boolean value `true`

```
$odd= true;
```

This uses whats called a terniary operator to print out a string.
If `$odd` is true it will print the first bit, if not then the second.  As you have set `$odd` to true immediately before, it will always print the first bit

```
echo ($odd == true) ? '<tr class="odd_row">' : '<tr class="even_row">';
```

This sets `$odd` to `!` (not) `$odd` so reverses the boolean to false
    $odd = !$odd;

*Sorry for the literal explanation, but I wanted to be thorough*