# Unexpected syntax error using php if shorthand

Tags: php

```
function a(){
//logic here
//else return false
}

function b(){
//logic here
//else return false
}

function c(){
//logic here
//else return false
}

a() ? b() ? c();
```

I want to run a first, if false go to b if false go to c but I got unexpected ';' error. 
One more doubt : if `a()` return false will it go to `b()`? or I need to set like `if(a() != true)` ?

Comment: That last line makes no sense

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `or` conjunctions.

Comment: try `if(!a())if(!b())c();`

Answer (score 1):

```
a() ? b() ? c()
```

is only valid as the start of

```
a() ? b() ? c() : ... : ...
```

which is why PHP complains of an unexpected `;`. You can read more about the conditional operator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080256/589924).

---

You want

```
a() || b() || c();
```

or

```
a() or b() or c();
```

PHP, like many languages, short circuit boolean algebra so only as much is evaluated, so it'll stop evaluating the chain when one of the terms returns true.

Comment: written the wrong id of duplicate post ... reopened question but still i think its dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, It doesn't solve the OP's problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax for operator ?: is `$sth? $forTrue : $forFalse;`. So if you really want to do this using it, your last line should look like:

```
a() ? null : (b() ?  null : c());
```

But I think it looks better and be easier to read if you use if statement.

```
if (!a()) {
    if(!b()) {
        c();
    }
}
```