# Using Link change content ORDERING BY DESC, ASC and e.t.c. of the SAME page

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink, sql-order-by

This is my view page:

```
<?php

include 'connect/con.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT newsvid.id, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.url, newsvid.vidSD, newsvid.published, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQuality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidTime  FROM newsvid, videoinformation WHERE newsvid.id = videoinformation.id ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<div class="id">#<a href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</a></div>';
  echo "<div class=\"vidTitle\">" . $row['vidTitle'] . "</div>";
  echo "<div class=\"imgCover\"><img class=\"imageCover\"src=\"" . $row['url'] . "\"></div>";
  echo "<div class=\"vidSD\">" . $row['vidSD'] . "</div>";
  echo "<div class=\"vidDetails\"> 
<table class=\"tableSD\" >
<tr><td class=\"tdBR\"><strong> Years: </strong></td><td class=\"tdB\">" . $row['vidYear'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"tdBR\"><strong> City: </strong></td><td class=\"tdB\">". $row['vidCity'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"tdBR\"><strong> Zanr: </strong></td><td class=\"tdB\">". $row['vidZanr'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"tdBR\"><strong> Quality: </strong></td><td class=\"tdB\">". $row['vidQuality'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"tdBR\"><strong> Translated: </strong></td><td class=\"tdB\">". $row['vidTranslated'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"tdBR\"><strong> Video time: </strong></td><td class=\"tdB\">". $row['vidTime'] .  "</td></tr>
</table> 
 </div>";


  echo "<div class=\"published\"><strong>Published: </strong>" . $row['published'] . "</div>"; 
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I need a **LINK** in index.php page  this bit "`ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC`" will be changes according to the clicked link.

EG:

```
<div class="mainLeftCover">
<a href="#>ASC</a> |
<a href="#>DESC</a> |
</div>
```

If I press ASC the  view.php page will show result **ORDERED BY newsvid.id ASC** and if I will press DESC same view.php page will show the result **ORDERED BY newsvid.id DESC** and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you require to add a parameter to the link url

```
<div class="mainLeftCover">
<a href="view.php?order=ASC">ASC</a> 
<a href="view.php?order=DESC">DESC</a> 
</div>
```

Then set a variable with the stub of the query minus ORDER part.

```
$query ="SELECT newsvid.id, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.url, newsvid.vidSD, newsvid.published, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidQuality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidTime  FROM newsvid, videoinformation WHERE newsvid.id = videoinformation.id";
```

Use [**isset**()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) with the [**ternary operator**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do) to either GET the parameter or if it is not set pass a default.

```
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'DESC';//Change to ASC if you want this as default
```

Use  [**in_array()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)to sanitise

```
$goodParam = array("ASC", "DESC");
if (in_array($order, $goodParam)) {
```

Then use `.=`    [**Concatenation assignment**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) to build $query.

```
        if($order == 'DESC'){
            $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC";
        }else{
            $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC";
      }
}
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: @Denis There was a typo in Code.  Missing close bracket  should be    `if (in_array($order, $goodParam))`

Comment: I have a question... ordering page... opening in new page and how to make it open in same one? I can show you full code if you need...

Comment: @Denis change view.php to whatever the page is.

Comment: the main idea was... by clicking asc and desc not the page will change... i need that the div will change....

Comment: If you want the div to change without reloading page you need to use AJAX. eMail me (see my profile for address) to discuss further.

Comment: daviestrachan@yahoo.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

- Make two links featuring ASC and DESC as an URL query parameter (say, `$_GET['order']`)
- On the server side be sure to check whether the value is either ASC or DESC to prevent malicious intent (i.e., `in_array(strtolower($_GET['order']), ['asc', 'desc'])`
- Append the parameter to the query so the DESC/ASC part is variable