# PHP Debugging. White page after inserting this code

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
        echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> LogIn <span class="label">LogIn to System</span></a>';
    elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
        echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '<span class="label">it is you</span></a>';
    }
?>
```

It's a bit of simple question. Can someone help me with debugging this part of code?
Then I introduce it in my php file, the page is blank. No content is displayed.
It's just white page, without any content. After removing this, I can see the content without problem.

Comment: blank page = something blew up and you've got all debug options turned off. turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors` and try again. in your case, syntax error missing `}` before `elseif`

Comment: You missed a `}` right here:  `elseif`

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
```

to:

```
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
```

See the "}"

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you are missing a closing curly bracket (`}`).

Here's my suggestion, loose the brackets if you have only one instruction per if-statement, as such:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
    echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> LogIn <span class="label">LogIn to System</span></a>';
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
    echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '<span class="label">it is you</span></a>';
```

Of course, you will have to put the brackets back if you plan on adding other instructions (eg. lines) to your statements.

Your code could also be shortened by:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
    echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '<span class="label">it is you</span></a>';
else
    echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> LogIn <span class="label">LogIn to System</span></a>';
```

Finally, you can also use [ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do):

```
<?php
echo '<a href="login.php" role="button" aria-expanded="false">';
echo isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ? $_SESSION['user_name'].'<span class="label">it is you</span>' : 'LogIn<span class="label">LogIn to System</span>';
echo '</a>';
```