# Recombining letters from two strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have two strings.
One is "`Aa ee Gg`", the other is "`Aa Ee`". Both are genetics for coat-color.

I wanted to generate a new combination out of both. The new string needs to have "one of the letters" of each string.

For example `A` and `A`, `E` and `e`, `G` and (-)

I tried to put the strings in arrays and then use these to make a new string.

Comment: Show me the array that you want to produce in code format...

Comment: Aa ee Gg x Aa Ee can have many solutions. In my example it would be
"AA Ee G-" but it also can be "aa Ee -g" always one "Letter" from String1 and one Letter from String2. So one A and one E and one G and so on ...

Comment: Why `AA Ee G-` and not `AA eE G-`? The latter seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: Or do you want to create a matrix of all possible solutions?

Comment: AA Ee G- or AA eE G- would give the same color. So of course it can be written like that. I am just used to sort from big to small letters :) Sorry if that was confusing. Of course from String1 there can only come an e not an E! Thank you.

Comment: @Darragh all possible solutions might be nice as well. Of course. I already would be happy if I can show one solution haha :D But yeah. All solutions would make my day! :D

Comment: Ah I just saw your update. I'll see if I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a slightly obscure solution but it gives you the result you are looking for:

```php
$first  = 'Aa ee Gg';
$second = 'Aa Ee';

$tokens = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    return ($a[0] ?: '-') . ($b[0] ?: '-');
}, explode(' ', $first), explode(' ', $second));

$string = implode(' ', $tokens);

var_dump($string);
```

This yields:

```
string(8) "AA eE G-"
```

A quick explanation:

1. You start with the two strings `$first` and `$second` with the values you want to combine.
2. Explode each string on whitespace to create two arrays, `['Aa', 'ee', 'Gg']` and `['Aa', 'Ee']` respectively.
3. Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply a callback to each element of the two arrays
4. In PHP it is possible to use array dereferencing syntax (`$arr[0]`) to dereference characters in strings. Here we're using a couple of [shortcut ternary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do) to return the first character in the current string, or return '-' if no character is present.
5. `array_map()` returns an array of strings, in this case `['AA', 'eE', 'Gg']`.
6. Finally, `implode()` the array into the string `"AA eE G-"`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! I have to admit my way was going directly to the wrong direction! That is exactly what I can use :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Interesting question - I was beavering away on another solution here :D