# shorthand if explanation ? mark operator

Tags: php, shorthand-if

For a template engine I would like to use shorthand if condition.
I need to check if a value is != null print out some line if true.
What I tried:

```
echo "test" ($user->affiliate_id !=null) ?
```

I have no idea what to write behind the ?.

Comment: that's the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), just read the doc

Comment: `$variable = $condition ? $ifTrue : $ifFalse` is equivalent to `if($condition) { $variable = $ifTrue; } else { $variable = $isFalse; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the PHP operators "?" and ":" called and what do they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-are-the-php-operators-and-called-and-what-do-they-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `$someVariable = $condition ? $valueA : $valueB` is equivalent to:

```
if ( $condition ) {
    $someVariable = $valueA;
}
else {
    $someVariable = $valueB;
}
```

So, basically, if the condition is `TRUE`, `$someVariable` will take the first value after the `?` symbol. If `FALSE`, it will take the second value (the one after the `:` symbol).

There's a special case where you can **not** define the first value and it is like this: `$someVariable = $someValue ?: $someOtherValue`. It's equivalent to:

```
if ( $someValue ) {
    $someVariable = $someValue;
}
else {
    $someVariable = $someOtherValue;
}
```

So, if `$someValue` evaluates to `TRUE` (any value different than `0` is evaluated to `TRUE`), then `$someVariable` will catch that value. Otherwise, it will catch `$someOtherValue`.

To give you an example:

```
function printGender( $gender ) {
    echo "The user's gender is: " . ( $gender == 0 ? "Male" : "Female" );
}

printGender(0); // Will print "The user's gender is: Male"
printGender(1); // Will print "The user's gender is: Female"
```

Another example:

```
function printValuesStrictlyDifferentThanZero( $value ) {
    echo "Value: " . ( $value ?: 1 );
}

printValuesStrictlyDifferentThanZero(0); // $value evaluates to FALSE, so it echoes 1
printValuesStrictlyDifferentThanZero(1); // $value evaluates to TRUE, so it echoes that $value
```

**EDIT:**

The operator `?:` is **NOT** called the `ternary operator`. There are multiple ways to define a ternary operator (an operator that takes three operands). It **is a** ternary operator, but not **the** ternary operator. Some people just call it the ternary operator because they're used to do it and, probably, it's the only ternary operator vastly known in PHP, but a ternary operator is way more general than that.

It's name is the **conditional operator** or, more strictly, the **ternary conditional operator**.

Let's suppose I define a new operator called `log base` that evaluates, inline, if the logarithm of a number `$A` with base `$C` equals to `$B`, with its syntax like `$correct = $A log $B base $C` and it returns `TRUE` if the logarithm is right, or `FALSE` if it's not.

Of course that operation is hypothetical, but it **is** a ternary operator, just like `?:`. I'm gonna call it the **logarithm checker operator**.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax should be like this

`echo (condition) ? write if true code part here : write else part here`

that means in your case it will be like

```
echo ($user->affiliate_id !=null) ? 'test' : 'not null'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Federinco it's called the ternary operator, the official docs are here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

The ternary operator works like so:

`condition ? true branch : false branch`

So an example would be:

`$cost = isset($discount) ? $total - $discount : $total;`

In the above example we check if discount has been set, and if it has we removed the discount from our current total, if not we just set the cost to the total.

There are other cool things you can do with the ternary operator like so:

`$name = $username ?: 'Guest';`

In the above code we are checking whether `$username` exists, if it is we set `$name` to `$username` otherwise we set `$name` equal to `Guest`

A word of caution though, the ternary operator can lead to readability issues if you abuse it, so be careful where you use it and don't sacrifices the extra lines of a standard conditional statement if the ternary operator is not going to be clear in what it is doing.

Comment: It's called the **conditional operator** actually. And yes, it is a ternary operator (since it takes three operands). When used as a binary operator (two operands), it's also known as the **Elvis operator** (`?:` look at it like a text emoticon).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo ($user->affiliate_id != null )?"test":"";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Your code should look like this

```
echo "test" . (($user->affiliate_id !=null) ? 'stringToOutput ifNotNull' : 'stringToOutput if is null');
```

Also, PHP 7 has introduced the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) which you could use. You can do this like this

```
echo 'test' . ($user->affiliate_id ?? 'ID not found!');
```

In which case, if $user->affiliate_id is set and not null, it will be printed
instead of the 'ID not found!' message