# Pluralize text in function

Tags: php, pluralize

I'm looking to be able to pluralize "Slide" in the below function:

```
// Changes the default download button text
function ps_download_button($args) {
    $download_text = 'Download ' . '(' . get_field('no_slides') . ' Slide)';
    $args['text'] = $download_text;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'edd_purchase_link_args', 'ps_download_button' );
```

This is my first stab at writing custom PHP functions. I've managed to find related code but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the above:

```
function plural( $amount, $singular = '', $plural = 's' ) {
    if ( $amount === 1 ) {
        return $singular;
    }
    return $plural;
}
```

Comment: `$pluralText = plural($originalText,$singularvalue,$pluralValue);` is the syntax to use the function you provided. The values which have `= somthing` in the function declaration line (top) are *optional*), so you can just as well write : `$pluralText = plural($originalText);` but you have the option of supplying specific information to the function.

Comment: it may bemore useful to you to replace the `===` with a double equals, `==` as that will still accept a string or float number as well as an integer. (on the `$amount === 1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use ternary for that.

```
function ps_download_button($args) {
    $amount = intval(get_field('no_slides'));
    $download_text = 'Download ' . '(' . $amount . ') Slide'. (($amount>1)?'s':'');
    $args['text'] = $download_text;
    return $args;
}
```

That's the simplest way, and no need for a function. If you don't understand how ternary works, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-are-the-php-operators-and-called-and-what-do-they-do).

Comment: Hi Phiter, thanks for this. This seems to output just 's' irrespective of value.

Comment: Sorry, it still outputs 's' irrespective of the no_slides value.

Comment: Try echoing your `get_field('no_slides')` and see what is its value before you apply download_text.

Comment: This is what I currently use, a number is displayed.

Comment: The value is bigger than 1?

Comment: Yes, I've tested on different values and have the same result 's'. With my original code I get "Download (x Slides)"

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. It was missing some parenthesis. Take a look at [this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa136064741f3d0d4ce3c559b4f381b0ad509623). It works. I'll update my answer.