# Array to string conversion, how to add an array to enter the database using addrow in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

how to add arrays in the controller?
how to add an array to enter the database using addrow in laravel?

need his help

> javascript addrow

```
    function formatRows(main, prefer, common,satuanu,kodeu) {
  return '<tr style="text-align: center;"><td class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" value="' +main+ '" id="kode_bmn" name="kode_bmn[]" class="form-control editable" readonly/></td>' +
         '<td class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" value="' +prefer+ '" id="jenis_barang" name="jenis_barang[]"  class="form-control editable" readonly/></td>' +
         '<td class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" value="' +common+ '"id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas[]" class="form-control editable" readonly/></td>' +
         '<td class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" value="' +satuanu+ '"id="satuan_ukuran" name="satuan_ukuran[]" class="form-control editable" readonly/></td>' +
         '<td class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" value="' +kodeu+ '" id="kode_unit" name="kode_unit[]" class="form-control editable" readonly/></td>'+
         '<td class="col-xs-1 text-center"><a href="#" onClick="deleteRow(this)">' +
         '<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></a></td></tr>';
};
```

> Controller

```
public function store_pesanan(request $request ,$id){
    if(!Session::get('login')){
        return redirect('/login')->with('alert','Kamu harus login dulu');
    }
    else{
        DB::table('tbl_paket')
        ->where('id_paket',$id)
        ->update(['status_paket' => $request->status_paket]);

        $data = new ModelPesanan();
        $data->id_paket         = $request->get('id_paket');
        $data->kode_bmn         = $request->get('kode_bmn');
        $data->kode_unit        = $request->get('kode_unit');
        $data->jenis_barang     = $request->get('jenis_barang');
        $data->kuantitas        = $request->get('kuantitas');
        $data->satuan_ukuran    = $request->get('satuan_ukuran');
        $data->status_pesanan   = $request->get('status_pesanan');
        $data->save();

        Alert::success('Sukses!', 'Berhasil Menambahkan Pesanan!');
        return redirect ('/daftar_paket');  
    }
}
```

[image]

please help me

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achive but if you wanna alter a databse with JavaScript you will need to use AJAX. Maybe this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808583/update-laravel-database-by-ajax