# Java "? :" operator?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

hi, may i know what is the java ?: operator called, i am trying to find information on how it works but i do not know what is it called, typing ?: in google dont give a correct result.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's the *conditional* operator.

Some people call it the *ternary* operator, but that's really just saying how many operands it has. In particular, a future version of Java could (entirely reasonably) introduce *another* ternary operator - whereas the *name* of the operator is the conditional operator.

See [section 15.25 of the language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25):

> The conditional operator ? : uses the boolean value of one expression to 
>   decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.

Answer (score 12):

ternary is the word you are looking for.

Comment: That's a description of how many operands it has... not the *name* of the operator.

Comment: Granted, searching 'ternary operator' instead of 'conditional operator' on Google works well, since you get fewer pages on `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @Jon: I know that is merely the description, but I was using the "what works best in google" logic.  I agree I didn't properly answer the question of "what is it called", rather the implied question of "how do I look it up."  But I have to admit that I don't think I deserved that many upvotes.

Comment: The more we encourage people to call it by its actual name, the better the Google results will get :) I'd get a perverse sense of satisfaction if Java *did* introduce another ternary operator, admittedly...

Comment: @Jon: ok, I can buy that.  I initially felt that "conditional" has so many other meanings that a google search would provide too many hits (22M) vs ternary (4M). That's why I answered that way, but I guess that is just enabling.  And the difference is irrelevant at that point anyway.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet just because Google gives you a better/accurate result doesn't mean that it should be called with that name.

Answer (score 8):

> #### [JLS 15.25 Conditional Operator ? :](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)
>
> The conditional operator  `? :` uses the `boolean` value of one expression to decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.
>
> #### [JLS 15.28 Constant Expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28)
>
> A compile-time *constant expression* is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - The ternary conditional operator `? :`

Thus, the Java Language Specification officially calls it the (ternary) conditional operator.

---

> #### [Java Coding Conventions - Indentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc3.html#262)
>
> Here are three acceptable ways to format ternary expressions:
>
> ```
> alpha = (aLongBooleanExpression) ? beta : gamma;  
>
> alpha = (aLongBooleanExpression) ? beta
>                                  : gamma;  
>
> alpha = (aLongBooleanExpression)
>         ? beta 
>         : gamma;
> ```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate

Answer (score 6):

This is known as the ternary or conditional operator (depending on who you ask)

It allows you to do single line conditional statements such as in this pseudocode

```
print a==1 ? 'a is one' : 'a is not one'
```

As Jon Skeet notes, it's proper name is the conditional operator, but it has 3 operands so is a ternary operator.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean for an if else statement?  Look up the word ternery.

```
int x = 2;
String result = x > 1 ? "a" : "b";
```

equates to:

```
int x = 2;
String result = "";
if (x > 1) {
   result = "a";
} else {
   result = "b" ;
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate

Answer (score 1):

it's called the conditional operator but very often called ternary operator (which is a class of operators all taking 3 operands however in Java only one such exits namely the conditional operator)

some times it's called the tertiary operator which is simply a language (english) usage error

Eventhouigh [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/whats-the-difference-between-ternary-and-tertiary) is for c# the same applies to Java

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate