# Another way of writing If statement in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Maybe this is a duplicated question to some other questions here but I could not find it.

Yesterday I saw a guy using a new way of writing the if statement by using `?` and `:` and I'm not sure what do they all mean.

If someone could point me out to a tutorial or an already answered question I would so much appreciated.

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: Don't use them too much, there isn't a lot worse then nested ternary operators.

Comment: @DesmondZhou oh! I see lot of Prof. java programmers use this operator. In fact they even use it when they declare a variable :S

Comment: @iMohammad yes thats what you want to use it for, use it for assignment to variables concisely but not as a replacement to if statements. For example, don't put methods with side-effect in them, and don't nest them. Have fun!

Comment: I've seen nested ternary operators before.  They're unsettling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conditional operator, it's a type of ternary operator

[wikipedia - ?:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

[wikipedia - ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Comment: wow!Ternary Operator. THANKS!

Comment: No. The name of the operator is "conditional operator" http://stackoverflow.com/a/798556

Answer (score 6):

```
(condition) ? (what happens if true) : (what happens if false);
```

Example use:

```
int a = 1;
int b = (a == 1) ? 2 : (a + 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a ternary operator. General form:

```
expr1 ? expr2 : expr3
```

If `expr1` evaluates to true, the returned result is `expr2`, otherwise it's `expr3`. Example:

```
Object obj = (obj != null) ? obj : new Object();
```

Easy way to initialize an object if it's `null`.

Answer (score 4):

(statement) ? TRUE : FALSE

Example in pseudocode: `a = (5 > 3) ? 1 : 0`

If the statement is true, a will be one (which it is), otherwise it will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a ternary operator, and it's a cute, if sometimes hard to read, way of writing an IF statement.

```
   if ( x == 3) {
      do-magic
   }
    else {
      do-other-magic
   }
```

would be expressed like so:

```
   x == 3 ? do-magic : do-other-magic
```

Comment: man tell me about it. I didn't understand the whole code just because of this ternary operator

Comment: so `?` simply means `if`

Comment: Essentially, yes.  It is most often used for assignment, as @ExtremeCoder detailed, but can occasionally be used for logic in much the same way as an IF statement.

Just wait until you start seeing nested ternary operators!