# Please help me understand this piece of code in Java

Tags: java

'm having issues understanding what exactly this piece of code does:

```
1.   HashMap<Integer, Integer> totals = new HashMap<>();
2.       
3.          for (int i = -NBR_STEPS; i <= NBR_STEPS; i++) {
4.              totals.put(i, 0);
5.          }
6.          System.out.println("");
7.          for (int i = 0; i < NBR_WALKS; i++) {
8.              int total_value = 0;
9.              for (int j = 0; j < NBR_STEPS; j++) {
10.                 int L = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
11.                 total_value += (L == 0) ? -1 : 1;
12.             }
13.             totals.put(total_value, totals.get(total_value) + 1);
14.         }
15. }
```

What I don't understand:

1. What does `totals.put(i,0)` do?
2. What does `total_value += (L == 0) ? -1 : 1;` do exactly?
3. What does `totals.put(total_value, totals.get(total_value)+1);` do?

I'm sorry that I'm asking this question, but I simply don't understand. Thank you:)

Comment: 1. and 3. Did you read the doc for hashMap ? 2. Search for ternary operator.

Comment: `HashMap#put`, ternary operator combined with the assignment operator and another `HashMap#put`.

Comment: I tried to read what hashmap does, but I'm not sure. It stores something that you can receive later on right?

Comment: Ok thank you @ZouZou and Jeroen Vannevel, I see the what to total_value does now. But I must admit the += operator confuses me^^

Comment: @user2966573 `myVal += 1` is a shorthand to write `myVal = myVal + 1;`

Comment: @ZouZou alright but how exactly does that work? What if myVal hasn't been defined ealier? It needs a value, like `int myVal = 0;` right?

Comment: the += operator adds -1 to itself if L == -1 else it adds 1. The expressione L==0 ? -1 : 1 is a special conditional operator in Java as as far as i know in c/c++ to

Comment: @user2966573 Yes you need to initialize the variable.

Comment: I'd really like to know where this piece of code is taken from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does `totals.put(i,0)` do?

Stores the value `0` at `key i` in the [hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) `totals`.

What does `total_value += (L == 0) ? -1 : 1;` do exactly?

`total_value += 1;` means the same as `total_value = total_value + 1`

? is the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566796/another-way-of-writing-if-statement-in-java/8566842#answer-8566831). The value of this statement `(L == 0) ? -1 : 1;` is `-1` when
`(L == 0)` is `true` and `1` when `(L == 0)` is `false`

`total_value += (L == 0) ? -1 : 1;` is the same as:

```
if (L == 0)
    total_value = total_value - 1; // subtract 1 from total_value 
else
    total_value = total_value + 1; // add 1 to total_value
```

What does `totals.put(total_value, totals.get(total_value)+1);` do?

Copies the value from hashmap location `total_value+1` into hashmap location `total_value`.  It essentially copies a value from the next location to the current location.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: A Hashmap saves key-value pairs. So the first argument is the key, the second is the value.

`a += 1;` means the same as `a = a + 1`

`a = b == 1 ? 1 : 2;` means the same like:

```
if(b == 1)
  a = 1;
else
  a = 2;
```

Comment: The first argument for put is the key, the second argument is the value.

Comment: Alright super thank you:) I think I understand my question now with the comments and this answer. Unfortunately someone thumbed me down:(

Comment: "The second argument for put is the optional index where the element should be placed in the hashmap" ... couldn't be more wrong! There is no order of elements in a Hashmap, hence no index. As dansalmo said: put(key, value)

Answer (score 1):

What does totals.put(i,0) do?
It adds a key, value pair to the map. The variable 'i' is the key and '0' is the value associated with the key.

What does total_value += (L == 0) ? -1 : 1; do exactly?
That is an If-else statement. The simplified version is as such.

```
if(L==0)
total_value += -1
else{
total_value += 1
}
```

What does totals.put(total_value, totals.get(total_value)+1); do?

It adds a key value pair to the hashmap. total_value is the key and totals.get(total_value)+1 is the value associated for the key.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

About the question n.2 
 A traditional if-else construct in C, Java and JavaScript is written:

```
if (a > b) {
    result = x;
} else {
    result = y;
}
```

This can be rewritten as the following ternary statement:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

in your case the condition is `(L==0)`
if this is true:

```
total_value=total_value+-1
```

and so...

```
total_value=total_value-1
```

if the condition is not true:

```
total_value=total_value+1
```