# What is the meaning of "X ? a : b" notation?

Tags: java, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

In some code a `?` is used to perform a mathematical equation.

What is it and how do you use it? Is it possible to provide an example and the reason for the final answer of an equation?

```
int count = getChildCount();
int top = count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically is the ternary operator:

```
String mood = (isHappy == true)?"I'm Happy!":"I'm Sad!";
```

if isHappy, then "I'm Happy!".  "I'm Sad!" otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you mean something like `x = () ? y : z;` notation? If that's the case, then the expression within the parentheses is evaluated as a boolean, if `true` `x = y` otherwise `x = z`

Answer (score 4):

```
int count = getChildCount();
int top = count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;
```

Means that the top variable will contain the value of `getChildAt(0).getTop()` if the `count` variable is greater than 0, else it will equal to `0`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are referring to the [ternary operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), which is used like this:

```
<some condition> ? <some value> : <some other value>;
```

For example:

```
int max = a > b ? a : b;
```

It's a shorthand for an `if` and is equivalent to:

```
int max;
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
} else {
    max = b;
}
```

but allows a one-line result in code.

When used well, it can make code much more clear due to its terseness. However caution is advised if the line becomes too long or complicated: The code only remains readable when the terms are brief.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` in an evaluative expression is called the *ternary operator*.  It is essentially short-hand for an `if() ... else` block.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). It's shorthand for certain kinds of if statements. Where you're making an assignment, like:

```
int dozen = (bakersDozen) ? 13 : 12;
```

Assuming `bakersDozen` is true, then `dozen` will be 13. If it's false, it will be 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
```

is the same than

```
int result;
if (a > b)
  result = 1;
else
  result = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

? Is usually a ternary (or tertiary) operator. So let's explain what it is doing.

```
myValue = (a = b) ? 1 : 0;
```

The first part is your condition. "Does a equal b?"

The second part is the true response.

The third part is the false response.

So if a is equal to b, myValue will be 1. If a is not equal to b, myValue will be 0.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation