# Java simple code line explanation needed

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Hello I have some problems understanding the fallowing code, could anyone help me get this?

```
private Comparable elementAt( BinaryNode t ) {
    return t == null ? null : t.element;
}
```

I don't understand what `t == null ? null : t.element;` means.

Comment: gefei got the issue,i didn't ask about the method declaration, or I would have specified that. Downvoting should come with more than that.

Comment: thanks for the helping atempt, but others helped me already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return t == null ? null : t.element;` means

```
if (t==null)
  return null;
else
  return t.element;
```

see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java

Answer (score 3):

It is a standard idiom that avoids a `NullPointerException` in case `t` is null. In that case, instead of dereferencing it to get the element, it just returns `null`.

Some people argue that this is a bad idiom because it only postpones the NPE, but, depending on the exact situation, it could be just what one needs.

Answer (score 1):

its a ternary operator (in this case checking for null), ternarys can be used instead of if/else statements

Comment: thanks i will check this 'ternary operator' :). gl