# Java statements: Obfuscated code - `?:`

Tags: java, if-statement, binary-tree, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

I am trying to read an implementation of a binary tree, and I ran across this one line of code:

```
if (...) {
   ...
} else {
    node = ( node.left != null ) ? node.left : node.right;    //this line
}

return node;
```

Can anyone tell me what this line means? My best guess is that it's a conditional statement of some kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called `Conditional Operator`.

In `expression1 ? expression2: expression3`, the `expression1` returns a `boolean` value. If it is `true` then `expression2` is evaluated, else `expression3` is evaluated.

So in your code snippet: -

```
node = ( node.left != null ) ? node.left : node.right;
```

is equivalent to: -

```
if (node.left != null) {
    node = node.left;
} else {
    node = node.right;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, and thanks again for the if-then translation as well!

Comment: expression1 and expression2 would be better than statement1 and statement2.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the **ternary operator**, since in most languages it's the only operator which takes 3 arguments. It has the form:

```
a ? b : c
```

and evalutes to `b` if `a` is true, or `c` otherwise. It can be used almost anywhere, but most frequently it is used in assignment operations, since it becomes very difficult to read in more complex situations.

On a side note, "obfuscated" is not the right term here - that is meant for code which is deliberately rendered difficult to read. This might more accurately be called "obscure", although it is a common operator.