# What is this programming statement called?

Tags: java, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

What is this type of code statement called? I've seen it in Java and C++ before, but I can't remember what it is called.
int someVariable = (true) ? 1 : 0;

Comment: This is called the 'ternary' operator. Please have a look at http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: There are hundreds of places where you could have looked this up ...

Comment: Like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Other_operators

Comment: To be fair, it can be incredibly difficult to search a general source of information such as wikipedia for a question mark.

Comment: @competent_tech, that was exactly my problem. Didn't know what to search for.

Comment: @Emrys90 you can use [Symbol Hound](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%3F%3A) to search these things

Comment: Or you could even just type out 'question mark'. When I didn't know what a ternary operator was, that's how I figured it out.

Comment: @NewAlexandria thanks, I just bookmarked that site.

Answer (score 6):

It is called [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator).

Answer (score 0):

Its ternary operator to avoid line of codes for simple condition checking

`int biggerNumber = a > b ? a : b;`

even more

`int bigNumber = a > b ? (a > c ? a : c) : b > c ? b : c ;`