# How to avoid a missing return statement in an if

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to return a Course object with this method but only if the object isn't null.

```
public Course getClass1()
{
    if(class1 != null)
    {
        return class1;
    }
}
```

I have a 'missing return statement' error because it may not return anything, but I don't want to return anything, not even an empty String, if the object is null. I am okay with  changing the method to a void

```
public void getClass1()

{
    if(class1 != null)
    {
        System.out.println(class1);
    }
}
```

But if I do that I can't call the methods in my toString

```
public String toString()
{
    return super.getName() + "\t" + super.getAge() + "\t" + getStudentNumber() +
            "\n" + getClass1() + "\n" + getClass2() + "\n" + getClass3();
}
```

because void types aren't allowed.

Comment: *but I don't want to return anything, not even an empty String, if the object is null* then you must make sure to **always** have the `class1` variable initialized, and the code can be reduced to `return this.class1`.

Comment: _why_ don't you want to return anything if the object is null?

Comment: The language simply doesn't allow what you're trying to do.  I suggest returning null, or some other data type that can express the various results.

Answer (score 7):

You can't have two different return types, your method must return a specific type or nothing (`void`).

The only viable solution here is to have it return a `Course`, or `null` if no course is available.

```
public Course getClass1() {
  return class1;
}

public String toString() {
  Course class1 = getClass1();
  boolean class1Available = class1 != null;
  if (class1Available) {
    // something
  else {
    // something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to return something, the Java language requires. You have a few choices:

- Return a blank Course object:

  ```
  public Course getClass1() {
      if(class1 != null) {
          return class1;
      }
      return new Course();
  }
  ```
- Return `null`.

  - This is fairly simple so I'll skip the code example
- Back out and throw an exception:

  ```
  public Course getClass1() {
      if(class1 == null) {
          throw new NullPointerException("class1 is null");
      }
      return class1;
  }
  ```

  - NullPointerException is unchecked so no explicit `throws` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather return null in `getClass1` if there is null .

If you don't want to have nulls in `toString()` you can simply use three argument operator:

```
public Course getClass1() {
    return class1;
}

public String toString() {
    return super.getName() + "\t" + super.getAge() + "\t" + getStudentNumber() +
        (getClass1()==null?"":("\n" + getClass1())) + "\n" + getClass2() + "\n" + getClass3();
}
```

it works as following:

`(condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false)`

[there's more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do) of this operator

Comment: Sure, but this way you call getClass1() twice, which may be a problem if it does some heavy calculation.

Comment: @PNS In this context it's only simple getter for some kind of attribute. JVM will even change invocations of `getClass1()` to `this.class1`.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be done.  If your method is declared to return `ClassX`, you must return either an instance of that class, one of its subclasses, or `null`.  It should be a responsibility of a method client (caller) to perform different logic based on the value returned (or null).

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is what it should retrun in class1 is null? Any default/dummy object or Simply null. If its not returning default or dummy object, just remove this if condition as its not useful.

Comment: Method is expecting some value to be returned. Either class1 object or null. Here if requirement is do nothing in class1 == null, then will prefer to remove this if condition. If requirement is to return some default object like new Class1(); then if condition is usful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no normal way to "return nothing" from a method, unless:

1. **The method has a `void` return type.** This is not applicable in your case, unless you use an instance variable (e.g., `this.class1`) and modify that variable in the `getClass1()` method (which returns `void`), but this is not a good programming practice and if you follow it, at least rename `getClass1()` to something like `update()`
2. **The method throws an `Exception`.** This  does not make much sense here, since `toString()` should not throw exceptions.

If `getClass1()` is your main concern, you can easily modify the `toString()` method, as follows:

```
public String toString()
{
    Course c = getClass1();

    return super.getName() + "\t" + super.getAge() + "\t" + getStudentNumber() +
            "\n" + (c==null?"":c) + "\n" + getClass2() + "\n" + getClass3();
}
```

To generalize this behavior to any method with an `Object` return type, you can have a simple method `print()`, like

```
public String print(Object o)
{
    return (o==null?"":o.toString());
}
```

and then wrap all methods that may return a null value, inside print(), e.g.

```
public String toString()
{
    return super.getName() + "\t" + super.getAge() + "\t" + getStudentNumber() +
            "\n" + print(getClass1()) + "\n" + print(getClass2()) + "\n" + print(getClass3());
}
```