# what is the meaning of this statement (chaIntVal >= 0x10 ? chaIntVal : chaIntVal | 0x60)

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Hi Please somebody can explain me the meaning of this conditional statement? This is a java code.

```
(chaIntVal >= 0x10 ? chaIntVal  : chaIntVal | 0x60)
```

Comment: Well it's just a conditional operator expression. It's not a statement in its own right. Which part of it are you finding hard to understand? Is it the bitwise `or`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: @JonSkeet,
Yes I don't understand the | gate in middle.

Comment: @user3022123: Then I don't understand how the accepted answer has helped you, as that's only explained the conditional operator part...

Comment: @JonSkeet,
It was hard to find exact answer helped me. But the accepted answer helped me to understand and with your answer too. So how can I mark yours as well as the answer?

Comment: You can't - I didn't answer, as your question didn't make it clear what you didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means:

```
int res;
if(chaIntVal >= 0x10) {
    res = chaIntVal;
} else {
    res = chaIntVal | 0x60;   // binary or
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) which means this.

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
```

It is almost equivalent to

```
if(condition){
    // when true do this
}else{
    // when false do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression returns chaIntVal as is if chaIntVal > 16; otherwise it will set bits 5 and 6 to 1 of chaIntVal (binary OR http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_or.html) and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

If the high bits after the 4 low bits of the value are not set (value in range 0-15), do set bits x11x xxxx.