# need to write this code by not using 0?0 form?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 
  System.out.println(countDigitX(8888,8)); 
}

public static intcountDigitX(int n, int x) { 
  return n==0?0:(n%10==x?1:0)+countDigitX(n/10,x); 
}
}//end of class
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of details about your issue?

Comment: Well do you understand what the conditional operator *does*? If so, it should be fairly easy to rewrite it. If not, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: yes here is the question : Write a recursive Java method countDigitx that takes two  integer numbers as input (a number n and digit x) and returns the number of times digits x occurs in number n:
For example if n=23242 and x=2 then the method should return 3 that is the number of times the number 2 found in n.

Comment: Put the question into the actual question and not buried in the comments please.

Comment: @ScottMcGready:  That's not the actual question, that's just the homework assignment.  The question is how to migrate away from ternary syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static intcountDigitX(int n, int x) {
    int result;
    if( n == 0 ) {
        result = 0;
    } else {
        if( n % 10 == x ) {
            result = 1;
        } else {
            result = 0;
        }
        result += countDigitX(n/10, x);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit:

```
         if(n==0) {
         return 0
         }else if(n%10==x){
         return 1+countDigitX(n/10,x);
         }else{
         return 0+countDigitX(n/10,x);
         }
```

Comment: This would not seem to return 0 when n==0, which the original code will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it as follows :

```
public static int intcountDigitX(int n, int x) {

        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n % 10 == x) {
            return 1 + countDigitX(n / 10, x);
        }

        return 0 + countDigitX(n / 10, x);
    }
```