# Java Programming - syntax

Tags: java

Can anyone help me understand the following line of code.
I have tried googling the query, but no luck.

```
public int playerTurn(int token) 
 {
  return token==P1 ? P2 : P1;
 }
```

Comment: Rather duplicate of [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/798545/205233)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is pretty much this

```
if(token == P1) return P2;
else return P1;
```