# Java: How to check if a string contains only numbers and hyphens

Tags: java

I simply have a program that must read a ssn (xxx-xx-xxxx) and determine if the given ssn is valid. I just need a way to check that the string only contains #'s and -'s.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog7 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a SSN:");
  String ssn = input.next();

  if((ssn.substring(0, 4).indexOf('-') != 3) || (ssn.substring(4, 7).indexOf('-') != 2) || 
     (ssn.substring(ssn.length() - 5, ssn.length()).indexOf('-') != 0) ) {
     System.out.println(ssn + " is an invalid social security number");
  }
  else {
    System.out.println(ssn + " is a valid social security number");
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: Seems a little over complicated. You could split the string around `-`s, check the substrings size and if they're #s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764731/verifying-if-an-input-string-is-a-correct-social-security-number

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression representing `xxx-xx-xxxx` where `x` stands for digit can be written as `\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d` (note: `\` in String literals is special character, so if you want to use it as symbol and pass to regex engine you will need to escape it with another `\`, so String literal representing `\d` needs to be written as `"\\d"`).

Now you can simply use `yourString.matches(regex)` to see if regex matches *whole* `yourString`

So simple

```
String ssn = input.next();

if(ssn.matches("\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d")){
    //here we know that `snn` is valid
}
```

should work fine.

##### Improvements:

You can make your regex more readable by using [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). For instance with `{n}` we can express how many times previous element must appear. So instead of `\d\d\d` we can write `\d{3}`.

Also `Scanner` has methods which support regex, like `hasNext(regex)` to check if next token can be matched by regex. If it is not, we can simply *consume* it using `next()` and ask for new value:

```
System.out.print("Enter a SSN:");
while(!input.hasNext("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")){
    String invalid = input.next();
    System.out.print(invalid + " is not valid SSN. Please try again:");
}
//here we are sure that data provided by user represent valid SSN
String ssn = input.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
String ssn = input.next();
String pattern = "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = p.matcher(ssn);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(ssn + " is an invalid social security number");
}else{
    System.out.println(ssn + " is a valid social security number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you hate regex as much as I do, you could also iterate through characters comparing to ASCII values.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Test A: " + checkSSN("123-45-6789"));
    System.out.println("Test B: " + checkSSN("12a-45-6789"));
    System.out.println("Test C: " + checkSSN("123-4"));
    System.out.println("Test D: " + checkSSN("123-45-20303"));
 }

 public static boolean checkSSN(String ssn) {
     int count = 0;
     for (char c : ssn.toCharArray()) {
         if (count == 3 || count == 6) {
             if (c != '-') {
                 System.out.println("Character" + c + "Not a dash, returning false");
                 return false;
             } 
         } else if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
             System.out.println("NaN, return false");
             return false;
         }
         count++;
     }
     if (count != 11) {
         System.out.println("Doesn't meet length criteria");
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

}

Comment: Avoid [magic numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). Instead of 45 simply use `'-'`, instead of 48 you can write `'0'`, and `'9'` for 57.

Comment: This is true. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see ASCII anywhere in here. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. All of the expected characters are one UTF-16 code unit so comparison with literal `char` values as you have done is appropriate.