# How this type of expression works

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me how the snippet below will be executed?

Code:-

```java
int a = 3, b = 4;
a = (a > b) ? a : b;
System.out.print(a);
```

Comment: Well which exact part do you not understand? What has your research found so far?

Answer (score 5):

It is the same as

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
if(a > b) {
  a = a;
} else { 
  a = b;
}
System.out.print(a);
```

Also see 
[What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 3):

This is a [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) (note: not particular to Java but it's widespread and implemented in many languages), and returns either the 2nd or 3rd argument depending on the result of the initial condition.

```
result = condition ? result if true : result if false
```

and as such it's shorthand for

```
if (condition) {
   return a;
}
else {
   return b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of a variable often depends on whether a particular boolean expression is or is not true and on nothing else. For instance one common operation is setting the value of a variable to the maximum of two quantities. In Java you might write

```
if (a > b) {
  max = a;
}
else {
  max = b;
}
```

Setting a single variable to one of two states based on a single condition is such a common use of if-else that a shortcut has been devised for it, the conditional operator, ?:. Using the conditional operator you can rewrite the above example in a single line like this:

max = (a > b) ? a : b;

(a > b) ? a : b; is an expression which returns one of two values, a or b. The condition, (a > b), is tested. If it is true the first value, a, is returned. If it is false, the second value, b, is returned. Whichever value is returned is dependent on the conditional test, a > b. The condition can be any expression which returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

line 1: a and b are defined.

line 2: a is set to the value of b (because 3 is not bigger than 4).

line 3: a is printed to current std out.

Answer (score 1):

If 'a' is greater than 'b' you'll get a = a, otherwise if 'b' is greater than 'a' you'll get a = b.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as the following:

```
int a = 3, b = 4;
if(a > b){
  a = a;
}else{
  a = b;
}
System.out.print(a);
```

And that could be rewritten as:

```
int a = 3, b = 4;
if(a <= b){
  a = b;
}
System.out.print(a);
```

The `?` is the ternary operator, which considers the code before as condition and evaluates the code before the `:` is it is true, and the code after `:` if it is false.