# Java: meaning of operand statement

Tags: java, operand

I found this statement in a classmate's code, and I do not know what it means. I cannot figure out the order of operations or the meaning from there.

Thanks in advance

return a > b ? a > c ? a : c : b > c ? b : c;

Comment: don't code like him!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 4):

This is using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

(`condition` ? `value1` : `value2`) evaluates to `value1` if `condition` is true, otherwise `value2`.

The nested ternary expression:

```
return a > b ? a > c ? a : c : b > c ? b : c
```

amounts to:

```
if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
} else {
    if (b > c) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

It seems to be returning the maximum out of `a`, `b` and `c`, so it could be more clearly written as:

```
return Math.max(a, Math.max(b,c));
```

Answer (score 1):

If a>b true then if a>c true then a else c. if a>b false then b>c then b else c

Answer (score 1):

If you write the statement in if else's it will look like this:

```
if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
} else {
    if (b > c) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java this construct (`?:`) is referred as ternary operator. This is how it works:

```
a=(b?c:d)
```

This means a is assigned value of c if expression b is true and a is assigned value of d if expression b is false.

In your case

```
return a > b ? a > c ? a : c : b > c ? b : c;
```

This means 
    if a > b is true then 
       check if a > c. if a > c then return a otherwise return c.
    if a > b is false then
       check if b > c. if b > c then return b otherwise return c.
which is equivalent to:

```
if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) {
        return a;
    } else 
        return c;
} else {
    if (b > c) {
        return b;
    } else 
        return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question here: [what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)
Pretty much it is saying,
return a if a > b and a > c, else return c
else, if b > c, return b, else return c.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is that:

`return a > b ? a > c ? a : c : b > c ? b : c;`

Means (parenthesized to make more readable):

`return ((a>b)  ?  ((a>c)?(a):(c))  :  ((b>c)?(b):(c)));`

Which is using a ternary operator, that translates (English) to:

If a greater than b AND a greater than c, return a.
If a greater than b AND a less or equal than c, return c.
If a less or equal than b AND b greater than c, return b.
If a less or equal than b AND b less or equal than c, return c".

Which is simply determining the largest value of a triple.
You could do something like this which is much simpler and easier to read:

`return Math.max(Math.max (a,b),c);`