# Java Nested If-else shorthand

Tags: java

```
if (getNo() != null ? !compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo()) : getNo() != null) {
  return 100;
}
```

Assuming `getNo()` is not `null`, does this mean that `return 100` runs if     `!compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo())` evaluates to `true`?

What happens to the last expression (after the :)

Comment: Regardless of the outcome, you should really consider expanding this into multiple checks or multiple lines. Less lines of code does not mean better. This piece of code means I have to read it 10 times in order to understand what it's saying. That's bad from a maintenance point of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: I'm trying to understand someone else's code, so i agree that it's not easy to read.

Comment: @SurfMan The biggest problem here is that the "else" of the ternary is the same boolean as up front--this could be perfectly readably written as `if(get(No) != null || !compare...`

Comment: I think I get it now, the "if" part is returning a boolean, and the "else" part is doing that too.

Comment: @chrylis I think you mean `getNo() != null && !compareNo...`. You don't want the second part evaluated if the first part is false.

Comment: @chrylis - probably not.  It seems to me that `getNo()` probably reads a number from some kind of stream, or other structure.  So consecutive calls to `getNo()` probably don't return the same thing.  I think OP needs to make sure that whatever happens, `getNo()` gets called twice.

Comment: Its necessary to use `code` tag to separate it from other text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a mess. Let me refactor things so I can see what's going on:

```
if (getNo() != null ? !compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo()) : getNo() != null) 
{
  return 100;
}
```

is the same as

```
Boolean mainCondition = getNo() != null ? !compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo()) : getNo() != null;
if (mainCondition) 
{
  return 100;
}
```

is the same as

```
Boolean mainCondition;
if (getNo() != null) {
  mainCondition = !compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo());
} else {
  mainCondition = getNo() != null;
}
if (mainCondition) 
{
  return 100;
}
```

but if `getNo()` is `null`, then we find ourselves in the `else` condition, which will set `mainCondition` to `false`, so we will not `return`, i.e. a simpler way to write this is:

```
if (getNo() != null) {
  if (!compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo())) 
  {
    return 100;
  }
}
```

or

```
if (getNo() != null && !compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo())) {
  return 100;
}
```

The answer is yes: if `!compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo())` is true, then the original statement will return `100`.

As for what happens to the part after the `:`, it will not be evaluated unless `getNo()` is null, however if `getNo()` is indeed `null`, then we already know the outcome, so it's quite redundant to include it there.

Comment: So if getNo() != null, then "!compareNo(getNo(), b.getNo())" evaluates, and  if it evaluates to true, then you execute the return, and if it evaluates to false, it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Pretty much! If it evaluates to false, then we would evaluate the last part of the ternary operator (after the `:`), but we already know that evaluates to false since what's there is exactly the same as the original condition. So the ternary will evaluate to false, so the `return` will not run. As you said, it doesn't do anything.