# What is the difference between else if and && or ||?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

Did what i write below the same thing?

```
if(number >= 0 && number <= 99){}
```

and

```
if(number >= 0){}
else if(number <= 9){}
```

I hope this question is readable
Thanks**

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. Why don't you just try it out with a few statements and see how it behaves?

Comment: If you had statements in your empty `{}` blocks, you would be able to check under what conditions they are called. You would find your alternatives are not equivalent.

Comment: The second `if` is redundant, because any negative number is less than 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is inside an `else if` will execute instead if the first `if` statement does not return true. If that `else if` does not return true, you can add another `else if` and so on.

```
if(number >= 0 && number <= 99)
{

}
```

The above code block will only execute if both conditions are true.

```
if(number >=0 || number <= 99)
{

}
```

The above code block will execute if both conditions are true, or if only one of the conditions are true.

You could also use what are called `ternary operators`

```
num = (number >= 0) ? true : (number <= 99) ? true : false;
```

The `?` and `:` are just another way of saying `if`, `else if` etc.

Ternary operators come in handy when you want to do condition checking within statements.

Comment: The "ternary operator" is formally called the [conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do).

Answer (score 4):

Notice, that in the latter case you have two blocks of code, so you can execute separate pieces of code on first and second condition. In the former, the block of code is executed only if both conditions resolve to true.

The first option is equivalent to:

```
if(number >= 0) {
    if(number <= 99){}
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you nest two if-conditions, you achieve the same thing.