# Hey can someone explain me the use of "?" and ":"?

Tags: java

I dont know the use of "?" and ":".

```
return value < current.value
                ? containsNodeRecursive(current.left, value)
                : containsNodeRecursive(current.right, value);
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 0):

Exactly equivalent to this:

```
if (value < current.value) {
    return containsNodeRecursive(current.left, value);
else {
    return containsNodeRecursive(current.right, value)
}
```

Just a more compact way of writing it. Usually used for short if/else conditions to not use five lines of code, but only one.

Comment: Better not to answer such an obvious duplicate, but link to the original question, where the asker will find much more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
return value < current.value
            ? containsNodeRecursive(current.left, value)
            : containsNodeRecursive(current.right, value);
```

equals

```
if (value < current.value)
    return containsNodeRecursive(current.left, value)
else
    return containsNodeRecursive(current.right, value);
```

that means

condition ? do if true : do if false

Comment: Better not to answer such an obvious duplicate, but link to the original question, where the asker will find much more information.