# What's ? in boolean from Java?

Tags: java, boolean

What is `?` means/do in boolean?

```
int temp = 52;
boolean weather = temp>50 ? "Too warm" : "Too cold";
```

Output:

```
> Too warm
```

Comment: it's short if else syntax

Comment: It's called a `ternary operator`.

Comment: `x ? y : z` evaluates to `y` if `x` is truthy or `z` if `x` is falsy.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/798545/499581