# Java syntax and logic help "?" and ":"

Tags: java, arrays, logic, primitive

What does this line do? Mainly, I'm confused about the use of "?" and ":" and what they do (what are they called?).

```
Integer b1 = b.length > 0 ? b[0] : 0;
```

Apologies if the question is repeated I haven't been able to find anything related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Java ?: operator called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798545/what-is-the-java-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: ternary operation

Comment: b.length > 0 ? b[0] : 0;  is equal to if(b.length > 0) { b1=b[0]; } else { b1= 0;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if b length is bigger than 0 it sets b1 to b[0] else it sets b1 to 0