# Unfamiliar Basic C++ Code

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does '?' do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c)

```
xo = ((temp.npieces%2)==1)? 1 : 2;
```

I can't figure out what this means in it's entirety.

xo is an integer (I think simply determining the difference between a naught and a cross)

temp is an instance of position which stores information about a naughts and crosses board (positions on the board of the naughts and crosses, the state of the game (i.e. whether it has been won, lost, or is undecided), and the number of pieces placed so far upon the board

npieces stores the number of pieces placed so far

%2 is obviously determining the remainder of npieces divided by 2, in order to determine whether this is odd or even, and thus whether naughts or crosses plays next

It's the piece at the end that confuses me, the `? 1 : 2` bit, I'm sure I've seen this or things like this before, but I'm afraid I'm not sure what this does. I know this is likely pretty basic stuff, but I was quite ill in my first year of University (I'm in my second year now) and missed odd fragments so I have irritatingly random, often embarassing, gaps in my knowledge.

(This is part of a mass of code for an assignment I'm working on - trying to make sense of a few hundred lines of code, this included. As this is an assignment, I am *more* than happy not to be told exactly what this line means - and indeed just to be pointed in the direction of a resource that explains `? 1 : 2` so that I can work it out for myself. Either an online resource, or a larger chapter in any textbook available in Safari Books Online would be very helpful, or, of course, a very brief explanation here.)

Thanks.

And my apologies for the un-specific question title, without knowing what the unfamiliar code does or is called, I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it.

Comment: It could be very well written as `xo = 2 - (temp.npieces & 1);`

Comment: @ruslik: If the intent is to do a modulo, I believe `2 - (temp.npieces % 2)` to be clearer. This kind of trivial optimization is done by the compiler anyway and tend to make the code harder to read.

Comment: The truth is that the ternary operator is hard to google without knowing the keyword apriori.

Comment: Yeah I've got to say, once I knew what it meant, it did seem to be an unnecessarily unclear version of `2 - (temp.npieces % 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xo = ((temp.npieces%2)==1)? 1 : 2;
```

if `temp.npieces` is Even (therefore division remainder is 0) xo is now equal to 2
other wise xo is now equal to 1;

Edit : It does not check if it is Odd, it checks whether the remainder is positive 1.

```
X ? A : B
```

is another way of writing

```
if(X)
{
    A
}else
{
    B
}
```

---

Edit2 :

The purpose of the conditional operator is not to be faster, or more consise. The conditional operator returns a value. `if` does not. That's the main difference. `Therefore x ? A : B isn't exactly the same as if( x ) { A; } else { B; }`

**Credit @ John Dibling**

---

in C Something is true if it is not equal to 0. (even if it is -145)

Comment: So it's like a very shortened version of an if statement?

Comment: yes. I don't know if it is faster though. Someone told me that, but I am not sure.

Comment: `?` is determining it's an 'if', `1 : 2` is effectively `answeriftrue : answeriffalse`?

Comment: In general (condition) ? (condition met) : (otherwise) is ternary operator.

Comment: @Muggen: The ternary operator is simply syntactic salt, and brings no benefit speedwise. Only additional questions on SO.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the modulo may also return -1.  Oh wait, you didn't mention it... But you almost did.  (-1%2==-1)

Comment: @Schedler:  The ternary operator (not really called that, its just the only operator in C++ that takes 3 operands) is sometimes the best or even the only way to do something.  Consider for example RAII where youwant to get either one thing or another depending on runtime conditions.

Comment: The purpose of the conditional operator is not to be faster, or more consise.  The conditional operator returns a value.  `if` does not.  That's the main difference.  Therefore `x ? A : B` isn't exactly the same as `if( x ) { A; } else { B; }`

Comment: Edited answer with your comments.

Comment: @John Dibling: Even if the conditional operator returns a value, this is nothing that the normal `if-else` construct could not do. Hence the conditional operation is only syntactic in nature. With the `if-else` construct one naturally has to introduce a temporary variable, but this only makes things explicit, which is a good thing IMHO.

Comment: You can't do RAII using an `if` without either creating temporaries or pointers.  If the RAII object is expensive, you may not want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool ? 1 : 2
```

is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). If `bool` is true, `1` is returned, otherwise `2`.

Comment: It's not really called the ternary operator.  It's just the only operator in C++ that takes 3 operands.  It's actually called the conditional operator.  The name "ternary operator" is colloquial.

Answer (score 2):

[Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 2):

```
xo = ((temp.npieces%2)==1)? 1 : 2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if((temp.npieces%2) == 1)
    xo = 1;
else
    xo = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a conditional expression.

It works like that:

1. `(temp.npieces%2)==1` is evaluated. This expression is true if temp.npieces is odd (and greater than 0).
2. If the just evaluated value is `true`, the result is the first part after `?`, i.e., 1
3. Otherwise, the result is the last part, i.e., 2.

You can see this code as a shorthand for

```
if ((temp.npieces%2)==1)
    xo = 1;
else
    xo = 2;
```

Please note that the condition `(temp.npieces%2)==1` does **not** really test if `temp.npieces` is odd. For negative values of `temp.npieces` we have `(temp.npieces%2)==-1`. So if `temp.npieces` is not unsigned, this code might have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

read it as this:

```
if ((temp.npieces%2)==1))
 xo = 1;
else
 xo = 2;
```

if npieces is odd affect 1 to xo else affect 2

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a ternary operator. Something of the form

```
variable = condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false
```

is a shorthand for something like

```
if (condition) variable = value-if-true else variable = value-if-false
```

Now ((temp.npieces%2)==1) is going to be true when temp.npieces is odd.

It does have the feel of a secret decoder ring, but the ternary operator has been around since before C had the ++.