# Is (4 > y > 1) a valid statement in C++? How do you evaluate it if so?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-logic, logical-operators

Is that a valid expression? If so, can you rewrite it so that it makes more sense? For example, is it the same as `(4 > y && y > 1)`? How do you evaluate chained logical operators?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090845/language-support-for-chained-comparison-operators-x-y-z)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The statement `(4 > y > 1)` is parsed as this:

```
((4 > y) > 1)
```

The comparison operators `<` and `>` [evaluate left-to-right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

The `4 > y` returns either `0` or `1` depending on if it's true or not.

Then the result is compared to 1.

In this case, since `0` or `1` is never more than `1`, the **whole statement will always return false**.

---

**There is one exception though:**

If `y` is a class and the `>` operator has been overloaded to do something unusual. Then anything goes.

For example, this will fail to compile:

```
class mytype{
};

mytype operator>(int x,const mytype &y){
    return mytype();
}

int main(){

    mytype y;

    cout << (4 > y > 1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, `4 > y` returns either `false` or `true`, which are the converted to `0` or `1` for the next comparison.

Comment: I'd label the parse as `operator>(operator>(4, y), 1)` to emphasise the fact that it's repeated application of binary functions, rather than some kind of n-ary function

Comment: C++ needs stronger types. Implicit type conversion leads to such subtle bugs.

Answer (score 8):

**Expression Validity**

Yes, it is a valid expression, assuming y is, or can be implicitly converted into, an integer. If it is not and the `>` operator is overloaded, it's a different story outside the scope of this question.

It will be evaluated left to right as `((4 > y) > 1)`.

Assuming `y` is an integer, let's consider the two possibilities. `4 > y` can return `true` or `false`. The next part effectively becomes `true > 1` or `false > 1`.

Given the implicit [bool to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion), there are two possibilities:
A) `4 > y` returns `true`. `true` evaluates to `1`. `1 > 1` evaluates to false.
B) `4 > y` returns `false`. `false` evaluates to `0`. `0 > 1` evaluates to false.

No matter what, the expression will evaluate to false.

**Rewritten Interpretation**

I assume what you intend is `((4 > y) && (y > 1))`.

**Example**

`(4 > y > 1)` is not the same as `(4 > y && y > 1)`.

**Logical Operators**

The logical operators (`!`, `&&`, `||`) use short-circuiting logic.

Given `a && b`, `a` will be evaluated. If `a` evaluates to true, then `b` will be evaluated. **Else, `b` will not be evaluated**. As for `a || b`, short-circuiting logic works in reverse. `a` will be evaluated. Since expression `a` is evaluated first, if it is false, there is no possibility that the entire expression will evaluate true.

Given `a || b`, `a` will be evaluated. If `a` evaluates to false, then `b` will be evaluated. **Else, `b` will not be evaluated**. Since expression `a` is evaluated first, if it is true, there is no possibility that the entire expression will evaluate false.

Chaining the operators is a matter of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Better to use parentheses and be clear rather than risk the wrong behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a valid expression (not a statement), but probably doesn't do what you want. It evaluates left-to-right, as `(4 > y) > 1`. The test `4 > y` will evaluate to either 0 (false) or 1 (true), and the entire expression will always evaluate to 0 (false).

Answer (score 2):

4 > y will evaluate to a boolean value of true or false.  The remainder of the expression is then essentially [true|false] > 1, which does not make sense.

Comment: It "makes sense" when you realize that `true` and `false` are integer values in C/C++.

Comment: Ted: No they aren't. They can be converted to and from, though.

Comment: @Gman: A technicality, but a relevant one. Semantics can be cruel.

Answer (score -1):

4 > y > 1 --> MAY BE ANYWAY if y - is class!!.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 struct num{ int n; };

 struct op{ bool v; struct num n; };

 struct op  operator > (int x, num n){
  struct op o = { x > n.n, n };
  return o;
 }
 bool operator > (struct op o, int x)
{
    return o.v && o.n.n > x;
}

int main()
{


    struct num y = { 2 } ;
    if (  4 > y > 1 ) {  std::cout << "4 > y > 1 TRUE" << std::endl; }
    else { std::cout << "4 > y > 1  ALWAYS FALSE" << std::endl; }
}
```