# Only Returning the first if statement? (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

This is the assignment I'm working on:

> Write a  program that prompts the user to enter the points earned for a course and determines the grade. The program should display the grade and the message string for the grade. Use 'if else' statements to determine the grade and the switch statement to print the message string.

I wrote the code and it executes without any debugging errors. The problem is, no matter what I input as my `PointsEarned`, I only get the output for F! For example, if I input "90":

```
Try Harder Next Time.
GRADE: F
```

What's the problem? Am I putting my switch statement in the wrong place? Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int PointsEarned;
    char Grade;
    cout << "Please input the points earned in the course: ";
    cin >> PointsEarned;
    if (0 <= PointsEarned < 60) {
        Grade = 'F';
    }
    else if (60 <= PointsEarned < 70) {
        Grade = 'D';
    }
    else if (70 <= PointsEarned < 80) {
        Grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (80 <= PointsEarned < 90) {
        Grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (90 <= PointsEarned) {
        Grade = 'A';
    }
    else{
        cout << "That is not a  valid input.";
    }
    switch (Grade)
    {
    case 'F':
    case 'D':
        cout << "Try Harder Next Time." << endl;
        break;
    case 'C':
        cout << "Good." << endl;
        break;
    case 'B':
        cout << "Very good." << endl;
        break;
    case 'A':
        cout << "Excellent." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please choose a valid input to receive your grade." << endl;
    }
    cout << "GRADE: " << Grade << endl;
}
```

Comment: I''m pretty sure you need something like `if (0 <= PointsEarned && 60 > PointsEarned)` throughout.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889522/is-4-y-1-a-valid-statement-in-c-how-do-you-evaluate-it-if-so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't test multiple values like you are:

```
if (0 <= PointsEarned < 60) {
```

This is not checking if `PointsEarned` is between `0` and `60`. Only **ONE** of those `<` will be evaluated at a time, which means you're effectively testing something mor elike

```
if (0 <= true/false) {
```

instead.

You need something more like

```
 if ((0 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned < 60)) {
```

instead.

Answer (score 6):

Comparisons of the form `0 <= PointsEarned < 60` work in Python but not C++. You should use `0 <= PointsEarned && PointsEarned < 60`.

Answer (score 1):

This `if (0 <= PointsEarned < 60) {`
is breaking the C++ language, change that for 2 valid comparation
`if (0 <= PointsEarned && PointsEarned < 60) {`

Comment: Nothing is *breaking the C++ language*

Comment: Wrong, it compiles and evaluates just fine but not how one might expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code and done few improvements:in the line else if `(90 <= PointsEarned)` I limited it to 100.Also the other commenters noted that you can't test multiple values so I rewrite that as they said.It now works fine!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int PointsEarned;
    char Grade;
    cout << "Please input the points earned in the course: ";
    cin >> PointsEarned;
    if ((0 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned < 60)) {
        Grade = 'F';
    }
    else if ((60 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned < 70)){
        Grade = 'D';
    }
    else if ((70 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned < 80)) {
        Grade = 'C';
    }
    else if ((80 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned < 90)){
        Grade = 'B';
    }
    else if ((90 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned <= 100)) {
        Grade = 'A';
    }
    else{
        cout << "That is not a  valid input.";
    }
    switch (Grade)
    {
    case 'F':
    case 'D':
        cout << "Try Harder Next Time." << endl;
        break;
    case 'C':
        cout << "Good." << endl;
        break;
    case 'B':
        cout << "Very good." << endl;
        break;
    case 'A':
        cout << "Excellent." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please choose a valid input to receive your grade." << endl;
    }
    cout << "GRADE: " << Grade << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression: `if (0 <= PointsEarned < 60)` means `if ((0 <= PointsEarned) < 60)` 
which means `if ((true/false) < 60)`

The above expression is not the same as the expression you probably wanted:
`if ((0 <= PointsEarned) && (PointsEarned < 60))`