# Warning comparison integer and pointer

Tags: c

```
int b[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *s = &b[0];
int *p = &b[1];
int *q = &b[2];
int *r = &b[2];
```

My question is when I compare `p < q < r` using `if( p < q < r)`, I got the warning message.

What I thought is, first of all, `(p < q) == True`, so it's impossible to compare boolean with integer( address value of r). However, when `True` is considered as integer, it's 1. Right? So, `1 < r` might make sense, in my guess.

What's wrong with my thought?

Comment: Please post your comparison code.

Comment: Don't you want to compare the integers instead of the memory addresses?

Comment: "So 1 < r might make sense I guess." The compiler disagrees with you.

Comment: Are you dereferencing pointers OR just comparing pointers? Please share the exact code for more clarity.

Comment: you didn't post the main part of the problem, but it's probably a duplicate of [Is (4 > y > 1) a valid statement in C++? How do you evaluate it if so?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8889522/995714), [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/995714)

Comment: C does not define comparison between pointers and integers

Answer (score 2):

`1 < r` doesn't work because `1` is an integer and `r` is a pointer. Thus the warning.

My guess is you (a) meant to dereference the pointers, and (b) need to replace the chained comparisons with `&&`.

```
if (*p < *q && *q < *r)
```

Comment: I got it how stupid question it is. How can I compare absolutely different data type......

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that the expression `p < q < r` translations to "p is less than q, q is less than r", which would be typical of a mathematical notation.

However, the C programming language doesn't necessarily follow mathematical conventions. What `p < q < r` actually translations to is `p < q`, which might be 0 or 1 depending upon whether that's false or true, followed by either `0 < r` or `1 < r` based on that previous difference.

As another user has pointed out, the proper way to write "p is less than q and q is less than r" is `p < q && q < r`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from:

```
if(p < q < r) {}
```

To:

```
if(p < q && q < r) {}
```