# Dividing pointer char array to other arrays

Tags: c++

When I printed it I got error like this `17:1733╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠17:╠╠`.
I couldn't figure it out. I would appreciate if you solve and give me a better approach? Thanks for your help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    char* time = "173324";

    char holdh[3];
    char holdM[3];
    char holds[3];
    holdh[2] = '\0';
    holdM[2] = '\0';
    holds[2] = '\0';

    int t;
    for (t = 0; t < 6;t++)
    {
        if (t < 2)
            holdh[t] = *(time + t);
        else if (2 <= t < 4) {
            t = t - 2;
            holdM[t] = *(time + t);
            t = t + 2;
        }
        else if (4 <= t < 6)
        {
            t = t - 4;
            holds[t] = *(time + t);
            t = t + 4;
        }
    }


    string h(holdh);
    string M(holdM);
    string s(holds);
    string datex = h + ":" + M + ":" + s;
    cout << datex;
    return 0;
}
```

It might be overflow of memory but I tried to prevent that by assigning `null` values. So if I have a problem in there too please inform. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget that literal strings are really arrays of ***constant*** characters, so your pointer `time` should be of type `const char*`.

Comment: what s _expected_ output?

Comment: `╠` is 0xCC in codepage 437. So basically you're printing a bunch of 0xCC "╠╠╠╠╠╠╠" which means you [printed some uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714), probably due to a non-terminating C string

Comment: @phuclv `std::string` are not c-strings, they are not null-terminated

Comment: @user463035818 I've yet to look at the code but std::string does contain a null-terminated string which can be accessed with `data()` or `c_str()`

Comment: [Is (4 > y > 1) a valid statement in C++? How do you evaluate it if so?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8889522/995714), [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/995714)

Comment: @phuclv you get a null terminated c string when you call `c_str`, but that doesnt mean that `std::string` is a c string. If you dont believe me check this out `std::string s = "asdasd"; s[1] = '\0'; std::cout << s.size();`

Comment: @user463035818 I didn't say that std::string is a C-string and you can mutate the string like that. I'm talking about the place the OP constructs the std::string from `holds` and if he forgot to null-terminate that array, the output will be undefined

Answer (score 4):

The expression `2 <= t < 4` is equal to `(2 <= t) < 4`. That is, check if the result of `2 <= t` (which is a bool `true` or `false`) is smaller than `4`, which is will *always* be as boolean results are either `0` (for `false`) or `1` (for `true`).

If you want to compare a range, you need to to e.g. `2 <= t && t < 4`.

---

More generally, I advice you to *not* use a loop for this. Do the assignments directly instead:

```
// Create three arrays and initialize all elements to zero
char holdh[3] = {};
char holdM[3] = {};
char holds[3] = {};

holdh[0] = time[0];
holdh[1] = time[1];
holdM[0] = time[2];
holdM[1] = time[3];
holds[0] = time[4];
holds[1] = time[5];
```

Much simpler *and* show your intent much more clearly.

---

And you don't even *need* the temporary `holdX` variables, as you can just get the sub-strings from `time` and initialize `h`, `M` and `s` directly:

```
const char* time = "173324";

std::string h(time + 0, time + 2);
std::string M(time + 2, time + 4);
std::string s(time + 4, time + 6);
```

And do you *really* need the *also* temporary `h`, `M` and `s` variables?

```
std::cout << std::string(time + 0, time + 2) << ':'
          << std::string(time + 2, time + 4) << ':'
          << std::string(time + 4, time + 6) << '\n';
```

And do you *really* need freshly allocated strings?

```
std::cout << std::string_view(time + 0, 2) << ':'
          << std::string_view(time + 2, 2) << ':'
          << std::string_view(time + 4, 2) << '\n';
```

Comment: a bug, second iterator is "end" of source string, i.e. it  is the element _after_ its last one.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie True, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. we essentially could just designate three references to char of each section and use their addresses. Just as another "simple"  code. But you got a good illustration how C++ can contract whole program written in "C++ dialect" of C  to a single output line :P

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Which becomes very simple with [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). :)

Comment: Too new but if I understand documentation right, yeah. I actually never saw an example of its use and it seems to be C++17. Because of platforms are a bit behind, it's mostly C++11\14.

Comment: Lovely story start to finish :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is an textbook example of bad use of `if()` statement inside of loop.

What happens that you repeat all same checks in every iterations, while you actually *know* where iterations must stop.

And you made assumption that if() checks every comparison inside its expression. It doesn't. It evaluates expression and checks if result is equivalent of  non-zero value or  boolean `true`. Thus `if(4 <= t < 6)` is a bug. It's an equivalent of `if( (4 <= t) < 6 )`. `(a <= t) < b` is always true, if b is grater than 1.

SImplest conversion of your code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    const char* time = "173324"; 
    // note, that making it non-const is a not standard compliant

    char hold[3][3] = {};  // zero initialization

    for (int t = 0; t < 6;t++)
    {
        hold[t / 2][t % 2] = time[t];
    }


    string h(hold[0]);
    string M(hold[1]);
    string s(hold[2]);
    string datex = h + ":" + M + ":" + s;
    cout << datex;
    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe even so:

```
string hold[3];  
for (int t = 0; t < 6;t++)
{
    hold[t / 2] += time[t];
}
string datex = hold[0] + ":" + hold[1] + ":" + hold[2];
```

But better you should avoid making loops at all, provided string got constructor that receives iterators for beginning and end of source.

```
std::string h(time + 0, time + 2);
```

Comment: "you made assumption that if() checks every comparison inside its expression" there is no comparison that wont get checked in OPs code, its just their precedence that OP got wrong

Comment: @user463035818 there are languages were `if  0 < x < 2` means  that x is greater than 0 and less than two. But C and consequently C++ do not use that syntax for obvious problems with implementation of it  that would be "close-to-metal".  It's not precedence , it's complete lack of understanding that C doesn't have _comparisons_. It have  comparison operator that return boolean value.

Comment: `0 < x` is a comparison and `(0<x) < 2` is another one ;)

Comment: @user463035818 two subsequent comparision operator calls, yeah. It's not a comparision though, which would be a predicate solution, not a boolean expression. Semantics. C\C++ do not work with predicates.

Comment: sorry I dont get why you think `a < b` is not a comparison. Maybe I will do some reading later, but dont think we will converge here

Comment: @user463035818 because C++ semantics consider it being equal to a call of a function `bool operator<(int a,int b)`. That's not how OP  was reading that notation though.

Comment: maybe we can agree on this: "(a <= t) < b is always true, if b is grater than zero."... but if `b==1` and `(a<=t) == true` then `(a <= t) < b` is `false`

Comment: @user463035818 fruits of distraction