# How do I stop this loop from repeating forever?

Tags: c++, for-loop

For homework we've been assigned I am trying to use a for loop in c++ but apparently I don't understand how they work that well. Here's the code:

```
{
   double L,W,E,A,H,B,I;
   L=6.5;
   W=2;
   E=450;
   A=2.8;
   H=0.5;
   B=0.8;
 

   I= (1/12)*B*(H*H*H);
   for ( double x = 0; 0 <= x <= 2.8; x + 0.1)
    { 
       double F,S,G;
        F= -((W)*(x*x))/(24*E*I);
        S= (6*(A*A))-(4*A*x)+(x*x);
        G= F*S;
        cout << G;
   }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a loop where x increases in increments of 0.1 until it hits 2.8, outputting the values for G along the way. But right now it gives me an infinite output of nan. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889522/is-4-y-1-a-valid-statement-in-c-how-do-you-evaluate-it-if-so) might help you out. Essentially, `(0 <= x <= 2.8)` isn't computing `(0 <= x) && (x <= 2.8)`. It's computing `((0 <= x) <= 2.8)`. Since `0 <= x` is `true`,  the expression is equivalent to `true <= 2.8`, which after `bool` to numeric promotion means `1 <= 2.8`, which is also `true`, so your loop never ends.

Comment: Also, `x + 0.1` will add to `x` but it'll discard the result. You want to do `x += 0.1` instead; that will actually update `x`'s value.

Comment: [How to format code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Admittedly the duplicate is a different language, but the problem is the same. The condition in your loop is always true because of that syntax misunderstanding, which of course causes the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop test and increment are wrong, you need

```
for ( double x = 0; x <= 2.8; x += 0.1)
```