# What is the type of uint8_t multiplied by boolean value?

Tags: c++, boolean

From the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/conv.html), I was trying to understand which type the expression will end up to be:

```
bool myBool;
[...]
uint8_t(255) * (myBool);
```

Am I guaranteed that `myBool` will be casted to `uint8_t` (a.k.a. `unsigned char`), or the whole result might be `int`?

Useful link: [bool to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion)

Comment: In general, this makes no sense.  Multiplying a number by `true` or `false` doesn't make sense.  Just like multiplying the number 42 by orange.  I suggest recoding to something that does make sense.  Let the compiler optimize it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tend to disagree with your comment: the behaviour is well defined in the standard.

Comment: So what is the semantic meaning of a number added together falsely?  Remember that multiplication is repetitive additions.  So you are adding *false* to a number.  Again, `true` and `false` are Boolean or logic properties, not mathematical properties.  They could be mapped to 4 and 5 or "frog" and "rover", and it still doesn't make sense.  This is a *hack*.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't understand your statement: The standard defines to what true and false are mapped too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the document you linked to:

> **5   Expressions**
>
> 9 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic  or  enumera-
>     tion  type  cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way.
>     The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type  of  the
>     result.   This  pattern  is  called  the usual arithmetic conversions,
>     which are defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> --Otherwise,  the integral promotions (*conv.prom*) shall be performed
>       on both operands.1)

and

> **4.5  Integral promotions**
>
> 1 An  rvalue  of  type  char,  signed char, unsigned char, short int, or
>     unsigned short int can be converted to an rvalue of type  int  if  int
>     can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source
>     rvalue can be converted to an rvalue of type unsigned int
>
> ...
>
> 4 An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with
>     false becoming zero and true becoming one.

In your case, both the LHS and RHS will be promoted to `int` before the arithmetic operation and the resultant will be of type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Both operands will be promoted to `int`, and that will be the result type.

In general, integer operands are promoted to at least `int`, or a larger type if necessary, and arithmetic is not performed on smaller types. This is described by C++11 4.5 (Integral promotions).

For `uint8_t`:

> 1/ A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

If it exists, then all 8-bit `uint8_t` values are representable by `int` (which must be at least 16 bits), so `int` is the promoted type.

For `bool`:

> 6/ A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

So that is also promoted to `int`, giving an overall result type of `int`.

Comment: Also if I do uint8_t(255) * uint8_t(myBool)?

Comment: @Antonio: `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int`.