# Is there a difference between float(x)/y and x/float(y)?

Tags: c++, floating-point, division

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std ;
  int main ()
  {

     int x,y ;
     x= 7 , y=3 ;
      cout<<float(x) /y << endl ; 

  }
```

What is the difference between `float(x)/y` and `x/float(y)`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Either will be converted to `float` to do the division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [similar question involving `uint8_t` and `bool`s in an arithmetic expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917913/what-is-the-type-of-uint8-t-multiplied-by-boolean-value).

The answers to that question apply here also, with the following additional information relevant to `float`s.

> **5   Expressions**
>
> 9 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic  or  enumera-
>     tion  type  cause conversions ...
>
> --Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be  converted
>       to float.

Both the operands are converted to `float` before the division and the resultant is of type `float`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical difference in your question.

The result of dividing two integers is an `int` (this is called integer division and what you get if you omit the `float` conversion entirely); if you then cast to a `float` you still have the `int` result, albeit as a `float`. The result of dividing a `float` and an `int` is a `float`; so you aren't *promoting* the `int` result to a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Very little.  With `float(x)/y` the value `x` will first be converted to `float` and then to `double` while `y` will be converted directly to `double`.  With `x/float(y)`, `x` will be converted directly to double while `y` will be converted to `float` and then `double`.  In either case, the division will be carried out as `double` and the `double` result will be printed.

So for your example, there is no difference, but if `x` or `y` was larger (greater than 2<sup>24</sup>), then the value would be rounded slightly to fit in a `float` if it was first converted to `float`.  This would then give a (very) slightly different result.

Comment: Where did `double` dcome from? Expressions with `float` operands are evaluated within `float` type. `float` is not promoted to `double` unless one of the operands is `double` already.

Comment: They may be (and generally are for all except for some embedded compilers) converted to double first.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, The C++ standard says otherwise (as part of the usual arithmetic conversions performed on both operands). *If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted to long double.
— Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.
— Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.*

Comment: @Chris Dodd: The language does not "convert them to `double`". If you are talking about some hardware-specific behavior, then it will be some hardware-specific internal representation (like 10-byte FP type on x86 platforms), not `double`. If some implementation uses `double` as an intermediate type, it is OK, but that would be implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: thank you chris dodd but can you give me the source of this information

Comment: I guess this comes under the heading of "compilers may use any level of precision they please for float/double/long double" as otherwise gcc fails to follow the standard.  In particular, depending on optimization level and other things it sometimes converts directly to double (ignoring the explicit `float`) and other times does not...