# Remove if conditions from simple function

Tags: c++, optimization, micro-optimization

I need to remove as many if conditions as possible from the two functions below:

```
inline int inc_with_1bit_saturation(int counter)
{
    if (counter == 1)
        return --counter;
    return ++counter;
}

void branch_prediction_1bit_saturation(int* input, int* output, int size)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] != counter)
        {
            counter = inc_with_1bit_saturation(counter);
            output[i] = 0;
        }
        else output[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

How can I do that and what `if` branch is absolutely necessary and cannot be removed and which one can be replaced by simple bitwise operations or something like that?

### Update 1

According to User [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089383/jsf)'s great tip, the code is now looking like this:

```
void branch_prediction_1bit_saturation(int* input, int* output, int size)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] != counter)
        {
            counter = 1 - counter;
            output[i] = 0;
        }
        else output[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

### Update 2

Thanks to [Cantfindname](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711645/cantfindname), the code became like this:

```
void branch_prediction_1bit_saturation(int* input, int* output, int size)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = counter == input[i];
        counter = output[i] * counter + (1 - output[i])*(1 - counter);
    }
}
```

And this completely solves the question.

Comment: Your code `counter = inc_with_1bit_saturation(counter);` is a very inefficient way to do `counter=1-counter;`  The `%2` approach in the first answer isn't great either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the if statement inside the loop:

```
output[i] = (int)(input[i]==counter);
counter = output[i]*counter + (1-output[i])*(1-counter) //used JSF's trick
```

True converts to 1 and false to 0, according to this: [bool to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion)

Comment: Bitwise operators might be even faster: `counter = (output[i] & counter) | ((1-output[i]) & (1-counter));`

Comment: or `!(counter ^ output[i])`  maybe `1-(counter ^ output[i])` works better if the optimizer is less smart.  `counter^=(1-output[i])` if the optimizer is really poor.

Answer (score 1):

function `inc_with_1bit_saturation` is equivalent of **modulo 2**. So you can replace

```
counter = inc_with_1bit_saturation(counter);
```

With

```
counter = (counter+1) % 2;
```

Comment: @Samidamaru: Initial value is zero. Thus, it can be only incremented. Then it will get 1 and with next call will be decremented, so zero again.

Comment: indeed, realised and deleted my commented. (Though it is the behaviour of the other function resulting in this behaviour, the function itself does not perform modulo 2 ^^).

Comment: It is much better to replace it with `counter = 1 - counter` (as suggested by @JSF) than by modulo operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
void branch_prediction_1bit_saturation(int* input, int* output, int size) {

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = (int)!((!!input[i]) ^ counter);
        counter = (int)((!!input[i]) & counter) | ((!!input[i]) & !counter);
    }
}
```

A is logic input[i];

B is logic counter;

The truth table for input[i] != counter is:

A B

0 0 | 0 --> (0 & 0) | (0 & !0) = 0 | 0 = 0

0 1 | 0 --> (0 & 1) | (0 & !1) = 0 | 0 = 0

1 0 | 1 --> (1 & 0) | (1 & !0) = 0 | 1 = 1

1 1 | 1 --> (1 & 1) | (1 & !1) = 1 | 0 = 1

The truth table for output[i]

A B

0 0 | 1 --> !(0 ^ 0) = !(0) = 1

0 1 | 0 --> !(0 ^ 1) = !(1) = 0

1 0 | 0 --> !(1 ^ 0) = !(1) = 0

1 1 | 1 --> !(1 ^ 1) = !(0) = 1

:)

Comment: You are assuming `input[i]` is 0 or 1.  That was not implied by the question.

Comment: mmm..yes.. change (input[i]) for (!!input[i]), and cast to int. Update.