# when trying to find '*' the program finds '.' insted in c++

Tags: c++, char, ascii

So I'm trying to write a code that deletes all comments from a giving code.
When giving my code a condition to check if the current char is '*' and the next one is '/' (end of comment) and try to run it, it accepts ./ as */.

The code looks something like that:

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LEN] = { 0 };

...Input and some code...

  for (int index = 0; index < MAX_LINE_LEN - 1 && line[index] != '\0';
            index++)
    {
        if (line[index] == '/' && line[index + 1] == '/'
                && comment_nest == 0)
            break;
        if (line[index == '/'] && line[index + 1] == '*')
            comment_nest++;
        if (line[index == '*'] && line[index + 1] == '/')
            comment_nest--;

        if (comment_nest == 0)
            cout << line[index];
    }
```

so i keep getting "comment_nest--" when the input contains ./

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You really should `std::string` when dealing with string.  It has very convenient find and erase function built in for things like this

Comment: You want `else if (line[index] == '/' && line[index + 1] == '*')` aso.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think find and erase are not enough alone. As I grasp the code, it should also handle nested comments (which are not part of C++, dear Roi)

Answer (score 8):

You've got

```
    line[index == '*']
```

instead of probably

```
    line[index] == '*'
```

in the condition near `comment_nest--;`

The same problem few lines above: `line[index == '/']`

---

C++ accepts it and do not throw error while being compiled because of automatic conversion **bool** to **int**. Take a look at this thread to get more specific information:

- [bool to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion)