# Eigen boolean matrix plus

Tags: eigen

I would like to do the boolean matrix plus. How could I do it in Eigen?
My following example only gives a scalar +.

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


int main()
{
   Eigen::Matrix<bool, 4, 4> m;
   m << 0,1,1,1,
    1,0,1,0,
    1,1,0,0,
    1,1,1,0;
   cout << m + m;  //should be logical_and here
}
```

How could I use the logical_and here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen does not seem to provide specific functions to work on boolean matrices. However you can use the fact that booleans are converted to 0 (`false`) and 1 (`true`) reliably (see [bool to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion)). Noting that `0=0*0=0*1=1*0` and `1*1=1` it is obvious that multiplication of the booleans as integers is the same (up to type) as logical and. Therefore the following should work:

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


int main()
{
   Eigen::Matrix<bool, 4, 4> m;
   m << 0,1,1,1,
    1,0,1,0,
    1,1,0,0,
    1,1,1,0;
   Eigen::Matrix<bool, 4, 4> result = m.cwiseProduct(m);
   cout << result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe one more question, how to do the boolean matrix multiplication?

Comment: What do you mean by multiplication. The logical AND is the 'multiplication' in the Boolean Algebra. Are you asking about the logical OR?

Comment: I mean the standard matrix multiplication over two boolean matrices. The + is OR and * is AND.

Comment: Then you seem to have a weird definition of + and * that is pretty non-standard. - Anyways I'll think about how to do OR when I have some time.

Comment: `(m+m).unaryExpr([](const int x) { return min(1,x); })` using e.g. `min` from `<algorithm>` should do what you want because `1+1=2>1`, `1=0+1=1+0` and `0+0=0<1`.