# C: Need to add 10 dollars to a total price for every so many miles traveled. How do I do this?

Tags: c

So the issue is I need to add 10 dollars for every 500 miles a product is shipped.

**So I came up with this:**

```
milesPricing = (miles/ 500) * 10
```

But I have to add 10 even if it's not 500 miles, for example, if they travel 700 miles, I'd need to add 10 for the first 500 and ten more cause the total goes over five hundred. How do I program this? I kept thinking for loop, but that would make me create an infinite loop to represent all possibilities unless I limit the loop and I doubt I can do this for the assignment.

Thank you.

Comment: `miles / 500 + 1`?

Comment: I don't understand how that would help here.

Comment: You could also use `ceil` to round up so even if you have 600 miles, you'd get 1.2 which rounds up to 2.

Comment: Assuming integer arithmetic, `milesPricing = ((miles + 499) / 500) * 10;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: You'd overcharge if it's exactly 500 miles.

Comment: @Stargateur: No need for the ternary. `(miles / 500 + (miles % 500 != 0))` should work just fine.

Comment: Note that the duplicate covers both 'round to nearest' and 'round up' (and the question included 'up' in the title for a long time). Ian Abbot showed the basic formula for rounding up.

Comment: @FredLarson I don't like mix boolean and integer type, even in C. Standard just say true is not zero :p.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Use `(miles - 1) / 500 + 1`, or `(miles + 499) / 500`.  One's subject to underflow; the other to overflow.

Comment: @Stargateur: Well, that's a matter of opinion. But I think you got the precedence wrong anyway. Need some parentheses.

Comment: @Stargateur: The C++ standard says `true` converts to one, `false` converts to zero. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369783/10077

Comment: @FredLarson My bad you right `(miles / 500 + (miles % 500 != 0 ? 1 : 0)) * 10`. Thank for the quote about the standard.